# Performance considerations for keySet() and entrySet() of Map

Tags: java, performance, collections

All,

Can anyone please let me know exactly what are the performance issues between the 2? The site : [CodeRanch](http://www.coderanch.com/t/203203/Performance/java/entrySet-keySet-Map) provides a brief overview of the internal calls that would be needed when using keySet() and get(). But it would be great if anyone can provide exact details about the flow when keySet() and get() methods are used. This would help me understand the performance issues better.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

First of all, this depends entirely on which type of `Map` you're using. But since the *JavaRanch* thread talks about `HashMap`, I'll assume that that's the implementation you're referring to. And let's assume also that you're talking about the standard API implementation from Sun/Oracle.

Secondly, if you're concerned about performance when iterating through your hash map, I suggest you have a look at [`LinkedHashMap`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html). From the docs:

> *Iteration over the collection-views of a `LinkedHashMap` requires time proportional to the size  of the map, regardless of its capacity. Iteration over a `HashMap`  is likely to be more expensive, requiring time proportional to its capacity.*

#### HashMap.entrySet()

The source-code for this implementation is available. The implementation basically just returns a new `HashMap.EntrySet`. A class which looks like this:

```
private final class EntrySet extends AbstractSet<Map.Entry<K,V>> {
    public Iterator<Map.Entry<K,V>> iterator() {
        return newEntryIterator(); // returns a HashIterator...
    }
    // ...
}
```

and a `HashIterator` looks like

```
private abstract class HashIterator<E> implements Iterator<E> {
    Entry<K,V> next;    // next entry to return
    int expectedModCount;   // For fast-fail
    int index;      // current slot
    Entry<K,V> current; // current entry

    HashIterator() {
        expectedModCount = modCount;
        if (size > 0) { // advance to first entry
            Entry[] t = table;
            while (index < t.length && (next = t[index++]) == null);
        }
    }

    final Entry<K,V> nextEntry() {
        if (modCount != expectedModCount)
            throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
        Entry<K,V> e = next;
        if (e == null)
            throw new NoSuchElementException();

        if ((next = e.next) == null) {
            Entry[] t = table;
            while (index < t.length && (next = t[index++]) == null);
        }
        current = e;
        return e;
    }

    // ...
}
```

So there you have it... That's the code dictating what will happen when you iterate through an `entrySet`. It walks through the entire array, which is as long as the map's capacity.

#### HashMap.keySet() and .get()

Here you first need to get hold of the set of keys. This takes time proportional to the *capacity* of the map (as opposed to *size* for the `LinkedHashMap`). After this is done, you call `get()` once for each key. Sure, in the average case, with a good hashCode-implementation this takes constant time. However, it will inevitably require lots of `hashCode()` and `equals()` calls, which will obviously take more time than just doing a `entry.value()` call.

Comment: +1 "Iteration over the collection-views of a LinkedHashMap requires time proportional to the size of the map, regardless of its capacity. Iteration over a HashMap is likely to be more expensive, requiring time proportional to its capacity."

Comment: But if you just need to access the keys or just need to access the values of the Map then prefer iterating over Set returned by keySet() and Collection returned values().
One more point, the Set returned by keySet() and Collection returned by values() are both backed by the original Map. That is, if you make any modification in them they will be reflected back in the Map, however, both of them don't support add() and addAll() methods i.e. you can't add new key to the Set or new value in the Collection.

Comment: @aioobe AS you have written "Thats the code dictating what will happen when you iterate through an entrySet. It walks through the entire array which is as long as the map's capacity."
Shouldn't it be ".....which is as long as the map's size" ?

Comment: Good good answer. I always prefer to refer to the source code as it is the ultimate source of truth

Answer (score 84):

The most common case where using entrySet is preferable over keySet is when you are iterating through all of the key/value pairs in a Map.

This is more efficient:

```
for (Map.Entry entry : map.entrySet()) {
    Object key = entry.getKey();
    Object value = entry.getValue();
}
```

than:

```
for (Object key : map.keySet()) {
    Object value = map.get(key);
}
```

Because in the second case, for every key in the keySet the `map.get()` method is called, which - in the case of a HashMap - requires that the `hashCode()` and `equals()` methods of the key object be evaluated in order to find the associated value*.  In the first case that extra work is eliminated.

Edit: This is even worse if you consider a TreeMap, where a call to get is O(log(n)), i.e. the comparator may need to run log2(n) times (n = size of the Map) before finding the associated value.

*Some Map implementations have internal optimisations that check the objects' identity before the `hashCode()` and `equals()` are called.

Comment: Additionally, if the map is a TreeMap rather than a HashMap, `get()` is a `O(log(n))` operation.

Comment: @ILMIian and Michael: Why the difference between TreeMap and HashMap?

Comment: TreeMap and HashMap are different data structures, TreeMap is based on a Red/Black tree.  A HashMap is a bucket and list hashtable.  In both cases the call to get() is not free and its cost depends on the type of data structure.

Comment: Java 8 ( & above ) has the *value* in `HashMap` implemented as binary search tree instead of LinkedList. See http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/180

Comment: Just a nitpick, but "where a call to get is O(log2(n)), i.e. the comparator for will may need to run log2(n) times" should probably be "where a call to get is O(log(n)), i.e. the comparator for will may need to run log2(n) times". The base of a simple logarithm is not relevant to big-O notation because all log growths differ by a constant factor. (In computer science "lg" is often used to mean base 2, and since it's the most common one to occur some of us just use "lg" whenever there isn't exponentiation or something else uncommon.)

Answer (score 15):

[Here is the link to an article](https://web.archive.org/web/20140209172758/http://www.sergiy.ca/how-to-iterate-over-a-map-in-java/) comparing the performance of `entrySet()`, `keySet()` and `values()`, and advice regarding when to use each approach.

Apparently the use of `keySet()` is faster (besides being more convenient) than `entrySet()` as long as you don't need to `Map.get()` the values.

Comment: You said in that article "This method (using keySet or values instead of entrySet) gives slight performance advantage over entrySet iteration (about 10% faster) and is more clean." May I know how did you get that value of "10%"? You showed no measurement nor any external data that contains such value.

Comment: @dantuch I'm not Sergiy, but the article makes sense IMHO. The article is old though, from 2008. You could always create a microbenchmark using Google's Caliper e.g. for the latest JDK if you're curious, please post the results.