# How to write a map into a parcel?

Tags: java, android

In my android application I have an activity containing a `Parcelable` object (implements `Parcelable`).

That object contains a map.

When I try to do the following in the `writeToParcel()` method:

```
parcel.writeMap(myMap);
```

I get the following comment from the API:

> Please use writeBundle(Bundle) instead. Flattens a Map into the parcel
>   at the current dataPosition(), growing dataCapacity() if needed. The
>   Map keys must be String objects. The Map values are written using
>   writeValue(Object) and must follow the specification there.

How am I supposed to do it?
How am I supposed to use the `writeBundle(myMap)` here?

Comment: You can get some help from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8254654/how-convert-write-java-util-map-into-parcel-in-a-smart-way)..

Comment: http://android-orchestration.googlecode.com/svn-history/r162/trunk/Orchestration/src/orchestration/android/parcelable/ParcelableAndroidTaskDTO.java

Comment: Thank you both, so there is no simple writeMap way.

It seems that I need to insert the actual map entries one by one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bundle is just a map. Iterate through your map, put each mapping into a newly created Bundle object and call writeBundle over it.
May not be the best solution, but, a workable solution.