# Android HashMap in Bundle?

Tags: android, dictionary, bundle

The `android.os.Message` uses a `Bundle` to send with it's sendMessage-method. Therefore, is it possible to put a `HashMap` inside a `Bundle`?

Comment: java AND android newbie 8) thnx to all!

Comment: Accept any answer if we solved your problem. thx

Comment: Solution is here: [Android - How to pass HashMap<String,String> between activities?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11155142/379693)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android - How to pass HashMap<String,String> between activities?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4992097/android-how-to-pass-hashmapstring-string-between-activities)

Comment: What is there is a HashMap<String, List<String>>?

Answer (score 186, accepted):

try as:

```
Bundle extras = new Bundle();
extras.putSerializable("HashMap",hashMap);
intent.putExtras(extras);
```

and in second Activity

```
Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();

if(bundle != null) {
   hashMap = bundle.getSerializable("HashMap");
}
```

because [Hashmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/HashMap.html)  by default implements `Serializable` so you can pass it using `putSerializable` in Bundle and get in other activity using `getSerializable`

Comment: I am getting error when try to serialize the linked hash map  Parcel: unable to marshal value com.SGID.DataClass.InvalidSubscriptionReasonsData@41bd2b98

Comment: Can i use this method for object which contains primitive data type and array list of another object??

Comment: If you are having issues make sure you are using HashMap not Map

Comment: you might want to cast the returned serializable object to hashmap by following ways (HashMap<String, Integer>)

Comment: This produces a warning about unchecked cast. Is this safe to ignore?

Answer (score 14):

According to the [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/HashMap.html), `Hashmap` implements `Serializable`, so you can `putSerializable` I guess. Did you try it ?

Answer (score 6):

Please note: If you are using a AppCompatActivity, you will have to call the 
`protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {}` (**NOT** `public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState, PersistableBundle outPersistentState) {}`) method.

Example code...

Store the map:

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putSerializable("leftMaxima", leftMaxima);
    outState.putSerializable("rightMaxima", rightMaxima);
}
```

And receive it in onCreate:

```
if (savedInstanceState != null) {
    leftMaxima = (HashMap<Long, Float>) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("leftMaxima");
    rightMaxima = (HashMap<Long, Float>) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("rightMaxima");
}
```

Sorry if it's some kind of a duplicate answer - maybe someone will find it useful. :)

Answer (score 5):

If you want to send all the keys in the bundle, you can try

```
for(String key: map.keySet()){
    bundle.putStringExtra(key, map.get(key));
}
```

Comment: I'm curious if there's any reason not to do this?  I've not used serialization much, and never bundles (new to android), so I'm curious if this is O(n) and appending to a bundle is effectively O(1) or not.

If they're not different in cost, not seeing why you'd bother with serializing it into another map.

Comment: @CaptainPrinny unless the map is the only thing you are mapping to the bundle, you might clobber values and you won't know if a key was part of the original map or just a value stored in the bundle.

Answer (score 1):

```
  public static Bundle mapToBundle(Map<String, Object> data) throws Exception {
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : data.entrySet()) {
        if (entry.getValue() instanceof String)
            bundle.putString(entry.getKey(), (String) entry.getValue());
        else if (entry.getValue() instanceof Double) {
            bundle.putDouble(entry.getKey(), ((Double) entry.getValue()));
        } else if (entry.getValue() instanceof Integer) {
            bundle.putInt(entry.getKey(), (Integer) entry.getValue());
        } else if (entry.getValue() instanceof Float) {
            bundle.putFloat(entry.getKey(), ((Float) entry.getValue()));
        }
    }
    return bundle;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using my kotlin implementation of Parcelable to achieve that and so far it works for me.
It is useful if you want to avoid the heavy serializable.

Also in order for it to work, I recommend using it with [these](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49078895/6241054)

Declaration

```
class ParcelableMap<K,V>(val map: MutableMap<K,V>) : Parcelable {
    constructor(parcel: Parcel) : this(parcel.readMap(LinkedHashMap<K,V>()))

    override fun writeToParcel(parcel: Parcel, flags: Int) {
        parcel.writeMap(map)
    }

    override fun describeContents(): Int {
        return 0
    }

    companion object CREATOR : Parcelable.Creator<ParcelableMap<Any?,Any?>> {
        @JvmStatic
        override fun createFromParcel(parcel: Parcel): ParcelableMap<Any?,Any?> {
            return ParcelableMap(parcel)
        }
        @JvmStatic 
        override fun newArray(size: Int): Array<ParcelableMap<Any?,Any?>?> {
            return arrayOfNulls(size)
        }
    }

}
```

Use

write

```
val map = LinkedHashMap<Int, String>()
val wrap = ParcelableMap<Int,String>(map)
Bundle().putParcelable("your_key", wrap)
```

read

```
val bundle = fragment.arguments ?: Bundle()
val wrap = bundle.getParcelable<ParcelableMap<Int,String>>("your_key")
val map = wrap.map
```

Don't forget that if your map `K,V` are not parceled by default they must implement `Parcelable`

Comment: Did you try to shorten with @Parcelize?

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin:

```
hashMap = savedInstanceState?.getSerializable(ARG_HASH_MAP) as? HashMap<Int, ValueClass>

putSerializable(ARG_HASH_MAP, hashMap)
```