# How to keep the textbox values in the listview while listview get refreshed?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-edittext

I have a list view and each row containing a `TextView` and `EditText` .
while click in the `EditText` box soft key board gets open and i'm entering the value.
After that while pressing back button to close the key board my list view gets refreshed and all the values entered in `EditText` also gone.

Please help me how to keep the values while key board gets closed?

```
if (ConvertViewP == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContextL.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            ConvertViewP = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_cart_row_layout, ParentP, false);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you that you use SharedPreferences:

[SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

write the values into your preferences by leaving the application and write them back when you start/enter your application.

works realy fine for me.

Comment: while closing the keyboard after entering value in the text box itself value gets removed, how i ll store in Shared Preference?

Comment: There is textWatchListener for EditText. Just try that to store data

Comment: I made a change in code, now im inflating layout only when the convert view is null, so the text is visible now but value is moved to some other row text box while closing the key board.... see my code in my question...

Answer (score 0):

You can hold it all just in one variable. E.g. having some hashmap in your `ListActivity`

```
Map<Integer, String> mHashMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
```

Where the *key* will be the **position of list item** and *value* is the **text** inputed into the `EditText` thanks to the listener set on it. ([Counting Chars in EditText Changed Listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4310525/android-on-edittext-changed-listener)).
And in `ListAdapter.getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)` you'll make use of `mHashMap` and will get the value by position to be set into `EditText` if any.

If you want to retain the values during the screen orientation changes, you can easily do it, cuz `Map` is `Parcelable` and can be added to the `Bundle` ([Saving Android Activity state using Save Instance State](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/saving-activity-state-in-android), [Android HashMap in Bundle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11452859/android-hashmap-in-bundle))