# saveInstanceState of Stack in Activity

Tags: android, android-activity

Is it possible to save `Stack` instance state in `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)` method in Activity?

I tried but i can't able to find a way to do that. Anyone, Please suggest me that is it possible or not. If possible how to do that?

Thanks.

**Update**

It is not a duplicate question. @androbin noted the same question which i mentioned earlier in the answer. Still the alternate question is denoting `Hashmap` where as my question is related to `Stack`. So I think it is not equivalent to the mentioned question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android HashMap in Bundle?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11452859/android-hashmap-in-bundle)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got that :)

I can able to use `savedInstanceState.putSerializable("key", stackInstance)`. Because `Stack` implements `Serializable` by default. I got this idea from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11453027/3049065).

Special thanks for @ρяσѕρєя-k