# How to pass list of maps using parcel?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, google-cloud-firestore, hashmap

I am trying to pass  `List<Map<String, Object>> FriendsInfo;` in data modal but I really don't know how to do it for this please someone help me to solve this. I know how to pass List but I dont know how to it for list of maps

**Firestore Document**

```
UserName="Alex"
UserAge="20"
FriendsInfo--
         |[0]--FriendName="John",FriendAge="23"
         |[1]--FriendName="matt",FriendAge="30"
         |[2]--FriendName="cathy",FriendAge="25"
```

---

```
public class UserItems implements Parcelable {
String UserName;
String UserAge;
List<Map<String, Object>> FriendsInfo;

public UserItems(String userName, String userAge, List<Map<String, Object>> friendsInfo){
Username=userName;
UserAge=userAge;
FriendsInfo=friendsInfo;

protected UserItems(Parcel in) {
UserName = in.readString();
UserAge = in.readString();
//how to use FriendsInfo here?

[...]
@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
dest.writeString(UserName);
dest.writeString(UserAge);
//How to use FriendsInfo here?
```

Comment: did u tried putSerializable()

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11452859/android-hashmap-in-bundle

Comment: Did you take a look at the documentation of Parcel? I cannot test this but there seems to be a couple of options that might be used like writeTypedObject or writeList etc.

Comment: @RohitKumar Is there a way to send FriendsInfo using parcel?

Comment: @AndreasBrunnet  writeList only work for List, it does not work for list of maps i tried it.

Comment: you need to implement Serializable to work in parcel. method is writeSerializable()