# How to use a Serializable class

Tags: java, android, object, serialization, backendless

I'm using Backendless as a backend service, it offers a class called `BackendlessUser` for saving and retrieving users. I'm trying to pass a User between two activities on Android by passing it as `Serializable` extra:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(PeopleActivity.this, ConversationActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("withUser", contacts.get(position));
startActivity(intent);
```

Since the class `BackendlessUser` implements `Serializable`. However when I run it, it gives me this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object (name = com.backendless.BackendlessUser)
at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1468)
at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1416)
....
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: java.lang.Object
....
```

Due to, I think, this variable:

```
public final class BackendlessUser implements Serializable {
    private final Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
...
```

How can I solve this considering that I cannot modify the `BackendlessUser` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of passing the object, you can save the reference to it in a singleton so that it's available between the activities.

You can extend the Application class and save there. The Application class exists all the time while your app is running and is a singleton.

```
public class MyApp extends Application {
  public BackendUser currentUser;
}
```

Then:

```
((MyApp)getApplication()).currentUser
```

Answer (score 2):

In Android you should use `Parcelable` which offers better performances compared to `Serializable`. For an explanation about how to implement it [take a look at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7181526/how-can-i-make-my-custom-objects-parcelable)

Also, if you need to use `Parcelable` on your map object, [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8254654/how-write-java-util-map-into-parcel-in-a-smart-way)

Edit: since `Object` is not `Parcelable` though you might want to follow Alexander's answer, or, even better, use a database for data persistence

Comment: Maybe you could explain him how to do that give that *How can I solve this considering that I cannot modify the BackendlessUser class?*

Comment: Yes, but how exactly is he going to save his class in there?

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `Parcelable` to pass objects between activities. `Parcelable` is Android's version of `Serializable`, so you use that. You can find more information on `Parcelable` [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html).

If you can't modify the backend user, your best bet would be to use Alexanders suggestion and create a `Singleton` instance of `User`. This would allow you to create/update you user from any activity.

Comment: He can not modify his class, how Parcealable will help?

Comment: @AlexanderKulyakhtin he added that requirement after I answered the question. I'll update it.