# java collections - keyset() vs entrySet() in map

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, linkedhashmap, keyset

I put a string array elements is a  map  where elements of string array is key and frequency of word is value, e.g.:

```
String[] args = {"if","it","is","to","be","it","is","up","me","to","delegate"};
```

then the map will have entries like `[ if:1, it:2 .... ]`

```
Set<String> keys = m.keySet();
System.out.println("keyset of the map : "+keys);
```

prints all keys: `"if","it","is","to","be","it","is","up","me","to","delegate"`

```
Set<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> entrySet = m.entrySet();
Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> i = entrySet.iterator();
while(i.hasNext()){
    Map.Entry<String, Integer> element = i.next();
    System.out.println("Key: "+element.getKey()+" ,value: "+element.getValue());
}
```

prints all key values pairs :

Using entry set prints all values:

```
Key: if ,value: 1
Key: it ,value: 2
Key: is ,value: 2
Key: to ,value: 2
Key: be ,value: 1
Key: up ,value: 1
Key: me ,value: 1
Key: delegate ,value: 1
```

But the block of code below should print exactly the same output as above, but it does not:

```
Iterator<String> itr2 = keys.iterator();
while(itr2.hasNext()){
    //System.out.println(itr1.next()+" ");
    //System.out.println(m.get(itr1.next())+" ");
    System.out.println("Key: "+itr2.next()+" ,value: "+m.get(itr2.next()));
}
```

It prints:

```
Key: if ,value: 2
Key: is ,value: 2
Key: be ,value: 1
Key: me ,value: 1
```

But if we uncomment line 1 in the while loop i.e

```
System.out.println(itr1.next()+" ");
```

and comment the line

```
System.out.println("Key: "+itr2.next()+" ,value: "+m.get(itr2.next()));
```

Then we get all keys: `{"if","it","is","to","be","it","is","up","me","to","delegate"};`

If we use `m.get()` with `itr2.next()`, then the iterator does not have few keys!

Comment: If you are storing many integer values, you should look into the fastutil library instead of j.u collections.

Comment: The keyset will not have repetitions, I guess it should not be having the "it"  string printed twice.  Which you are printing after this call
 Set<String> keys = m.keySet();
System.out.println("keyset of the map : "+keys);

Comment: See also [Performance considerations for keySet() and entrySet() of Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3870064/performance-considerations-for-keyset-and-entryset-of-map/3870093#3870093)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Every call to the `Iterator.next()` moves the iterator to the next element. If you want to use the current element in more than one statement or expression, you have to store it in a local variable. Or even better, why don't you simply use a for-each loop?

```
for (String key : map.keySet()) {
    System.out.println(key + ":" + map.get(key));
}
```

Moreover, loop over the entrySet is faster, because you don't query the map twice for each key. Also `Map.Entry` implementations usually implement the `toString()` method, so you don't have to print the key-value pair manually.

```
for (Entry<String, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(entry);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for mentioning this very important point: use the entry set to avoid the unnecessary overhead of the call to `get()`.

Comment: "because you don't query the map twice for each key"
why twice? I thought you query only once when you do 
map.get(key) ?

Comment: @HenryNguyen I believe he meant that you're querying it once when you use the iterator to fetch the key

Answer (score 3):

Every time you call itr2.next() you are getting a distinct value. Not the same value. You should only call this once in the loop.

```
Iterator<String> itr2 = keys.iterator();
    while(itr2.hasNext()){
        String v = itr2.next();
        System.out.println("Key: "+v+" ,value: "+m.get(v));
    }
```

Comment: In Effective Java book the same bug is mentioned and that's why using foreach loop is the preferred one.

Comment: It was lucky of you to have even number of entries in your map, other wise you would encounter a RuntimeException

Comment: +1 to Amir's comment. Unless you need to remove items from the collection, using the Iterator directly will only introduce the possibility of errors. You should use the foreach looping style for simple read loops.

Answer (score 3):

Traversal over the large map `entrySet()` is much better than the `keySet()`. Check [this](http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/04/01/performance-comparison-of-different-ways-to-iterate-over-hashmap/) tutorial how they optimise the traversal over the large object with the help of `entrySet(`) and how it helps for performance tuning.

Answer (score 1):

An `Iterator` moves forward only, if it read it once, it's done. Your

```
m.get(itr2.next());
```

is reading the next value of `itr2.next();`, that is why you are missing a few (actually not a few, every other) keys.

Answer (score 0):

To make things simple , please note that every time you do `itr2.next()` the pointer moves to the next element i.e. here if you notice carefully, then the output is perfectly fine according to the logic you have written .

This may help you in understanding better:

1st Iteration of While loop(pointer is before the 1st element):

Key: if ,value: 2  `{itr2.next()=if; m.get(itr2.next()=it)=>2}`

2nd Iteration of While loop(pointer is before the 3rd element):

Key: is ,value: 2 `{itr2.next()=is; m.get(itr2.next()=to)=>2}`

3rd Iteration of While loop(pointer is before the 5th element):

Key: be ,value: 1 `{itr2.next()="be"; m.get(itr2.next()="up")=>"1"}`

4th Iteration of While loop(pointer is before the 7th element):

Key: me ,value: 1 `{itr2.next()="me"; m.get(itr2.next()="delegate")=>"1"}`

Key: if ,value: 1
Key: it ,value: 2
Key: is ,value: 2
Key: to ,value: 2
Key: be ,value: 1
Key: up ,value: 1
Key: me ,value: 1
Key: delegate ,value: 1

It prints:

Key: if ,value: 2
Key: is ,value: 2
Key: be ,value: 1
Key: me ,value: 1