# How to find unique words given a list of words in R

Tags: r, unique, words

I have a list of words

```
a = c("when","to","use","each","effect","","recognizing","each","effect","?",":")
a
[1] "when"        "to"          "use"         "each"       
[5] "effect"      ""            "recognizing" "each"       
[9] "effect"      "?"           ":"
```

This list could have contained thousands of words. How can I effectively find out the unique words, i.e. "when" "to" "use" "each" "effect" "recognizing"?

I am trying to avoid for loops whenever possible.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried a bit of a search? Unique entries are given by `unique`, surprisingly.

Comment: Add all to a [KeySet][1] which will take care 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8962459/java-collections-keyset-vs-entryset-in-map

Comment: Sorry for asking such a dumb question. I am a new comer to the R game. I didn't know "unique" exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
unique(a)
```

You might also like

```
table(a)
```

Comment: Thanks, I was searching online for like a hour. Didn't know it's this easy!

Comment: First thing to try is type `?unique` (or whatever) into R, if that comes up empty then `??unique`, if that comes up empty then web search.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a hashmap to maintain the list instead of using an array. It would automatically maintain the uniqueness of your data.