# parsing on HashMap in Java

Tags: java, parsing, hashmap, key

I've simple question.

I set:

```
HashMap<A, B> myMap = new HashMap<A, B>();

...
myMap.put(...)
...
```

Now I want to Loop through myMap and get all the keys (of type A). how can I do that?

I want to get all keys from myMap by loop, and send them to "void myFunction(A param){...}".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how you can get the key set:

```
Set<A> keys = myMap.keySet();
```

I don't know what "passing on" means.  I don't know what "parsing" means for a HashMap, either.  Except for getting the keys out of the Map, this question makes no sense whatsoever.  Voting to close.

Comment: Like that?
Set<A> keys = myMap.keySet();
for(A key : keys)
    myFunction(key) ;

Answer (score 8):

This is a more generic answer based on question title.

### Parsing keys & values using `entrySet()`

```
HashMap<A, B> myMap = new HashMap<A, B>();

...
myMap.put(key, value);
...

for (Entry<A, B> e : myMap.entrySet()) {
    A key    = e.getKey();
    B value  = e.getValue();
}

//// or using an iterator:

// retrieve a set of the entries
Set<Entry<A, B>> entries = myMap.entrySet();
// parse the set
Iterator<Entry<A, B>> it = entries.iterator();
while(it.hasNext()) {
    Entry<A, B> e = it.next();
    A key   = e.getKey();
    B value = e.getValue();
}
```

### Parsing keys using `keySet()`

```
HashMap<A, B> myMap = new HashMap<A, B>();

...
myMap.put(key, value);
...

for (A key   : myMap.keySet()) {
     B value = myMap.get(key);  //get() is less efficient 
}                               //than above e.getValue()

// for parsing using a Set.iterator see example above
```

See more details about `entrySet()` vs `keySet()` on question [Performance considerations for keySet() and entrySet() of Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3870064).

### Parsing values using `values()`

```
HashMap<A, B> myMap = new HashMap<A, B>();

...
myMap.put(key, value);
...

for (B value : myMap.values()) {
    ...
}

//// or using an iterator:

// retrieve a collection of the values (type B)
Collection<B> c = myMap.values();   
// parse the collection
Iterator<B> it = c.iterator();
while(it.hasNext())
  B value = it.next();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

map.keySet() will return you the set containing all keys .. from here you can parse the set and get all the keys

Answer (score 1):

myMap.keySet() ? Not sure what you mean actually.

Answer (score 1):

After passing the map to wherever you're passing it to, the method/class ending up with the map would make the following call to get the set of keys in the map.

```
Set<A> keys = myMap.keySet();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Google Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) for filtering your collections. An examples for filtering, ordering etc can be found [here](http://codemunchies.com/2009/11/functional-java-filtering-and-ordering-with-google-collections-part-3/)

Answer (score 0):

if u want to get all key value pair from map
use map.keyset() it will return all keys in a set 
now u can use iterator to iterate all key values 
and use it in map.get(key).

Answer (score 0):

If you will not remove elements from your map, you can use this:

```java
for(A k:myMap.keySet()) {
    //the correspending value is myMap.get(k))
}
```

But if you want to remove elements from your map you have to use an iterator. Here is an exemple to show you:

```java
public class TutoMap {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Create a map
        Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>();

        //add some elements to the map
        map.put(0, "a");
        map.put(5, "b");
        map.put(3, "c");
        map.put(4, "e");
        map.put(10, "d");

        //get the iterator of the Entry set
        Iterator iter = map.entrySet().iterator();

        //try to remove element of key = 4
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry<Integer, String> ele = (Map.Entry<Integer, String>) iter.next();
            if (ele.getKey() == 4) {
                iter.remove();
            }
        }
    }
}
```