# Getting the key and its specific value from map

Tags: java, dictionary, set

I am using Map as follows

```
Map<String, String> propMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
```

and I saw that there is two methods that I can use `keySet()` (to get the list of keys)
and values to get the list of values but my question is how to relate between them
for example for key1 the value is 2.

I thought to use get value like follows

```
    Map<String, String> propMap2 = propterm.getPropMap();
    Set<String> keySet = propMap2.keySet();
```

But how I relate it to his respective value ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `propMap.entrySet()` method which returns a `Map.Entry` of `key, value`, if you want to use every pair of `key` and `value`: -

```
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry: propMap.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " : " + entry.getValue());
}
```

---

Or, if you want to know how to do this with `propMap.keySet()`, you can iterate over the `Set<Key>` you obtain, and for each key, use `propMap.get(key)`, to get the value of a particular key: -

```
Set<String> keySet = propMap2.keySet();

for (String key: keySet) {
    System.out.println(propMap.get(key));
}
```

---

From an answer from [**this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3870064/performance-considerations-for-keyset-and-entryset-of-map): -

With the later approach, if you are regularly accessing the `key-value` pair, then for each key, the `map.get()` method is called, which - in the case of a `HashMap` - requires that the `hashCode()` and `equals()` methods of the `key` object be evaluated in order to find the associated value*. In the first case `(entrySet)`, that extra work is eliminated.

Comment: @Cratylus.. Take a look at this post: - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3870064/performance-considerations-for-keyset-and-entryset-of-map