# Why doesn't a Java method with argument Collection<? extends V> accept Set<V>?

Tags: java, collections, set

Recently, I've been using a lot of [Guava Multimap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html).

Occasionally, I need to convert between a `Multimap<K,V>` and `Map<K, Collection<V>`. One direction is already provided by the Guava API: [`Multimap#asMap()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html#asMap()). For the other direction, I wrote a simple utility method as follows:

```
public static <K,V> Multimap<K,V> multimapFromMap(Map<K, Collection<V>> map) {
    Multimap<K,V> mmap = HashMultimap.create();
    for (Map.Entry<K,Collection<V>> entry : map.entrySet())
        mmap.putAll(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    return mmap;
}
```

But when I tried writing

```
Map<String, Set<String>> aMap = ... ; // obtained from elsewhere
Multimap<String, String> mMap = multimapFromMap(aMap);
```

I get this error message:

*`multimapFromMap(java.util.Map<String, java.util.Collection<?>>) cannot be applied to (java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.util.Set<java.lang.String>>)`*

But since the `Set` interface extends the `Collection` interface, shouldn't my code be okay?

From [Oracle Java Generics tutorial page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/inheritance.html), I see the example " ... `ArrayList<E>` implements `List<E>`, and `List<E>` extends `Collection<E>`. So `ArrayList<String>` is a subtype of `List<String>`, which is a subtype of `Collection<String>`. **So long as you do not vary the type argument, the subtyping relationship is preserved between the types**."

**Additions based on comments**

1. I replaced `V` with `String` in the `multimapFromMap` method, just to reassure myself that I wasn't getting some generics-related concepts confused, but the error persists with `?` replaced with `java.lang.Object` in the error message.

Comment: Presumably your code is wrong, as you're assigning `mMap`  to a `Map`. Please post an actual SSCCE.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I'm not so sure.

Comment: I'm using Java 8. To be precise, JDK1.8.0_20.

Comment: Incidentally, your algorithm is very inefficient. You should use the `entrySet()`, not call `get` for each key.

Comment: @BoristheSpider You should always explain why.

Comment: Just FYI, I found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3870093/1011791
Otherwise, that would have been my next question on SO :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not that you can't use a `Set<V>` where a method expects a `Collection<? extends V>`, it's that `Map<K, Set<V>>` is not a subtype of `Map<K, Collection<V>>`.

What *would* work is if you changed your method to accept `Map<K, ? extends Collection<V>>`.

The reason for this is discussed in many other StackOverflowQuestions, including [Is List<Dog> a subclass of List<Animal>? Why aren't Java's generics implicitly polymorphic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicitly-p?lq=1) .  (In the analogy, `Dog` is `Set<V>` and `Animal` is `Collection<V>`.)

Comment: Ah, I see. I did see that question before asking this one (even SoritriosDelimanolis pointed it out). But I completely messed up the analogy.