# Sort the values in a map of type Map<String, List<String>>

Tags: java, list, collections, hashmap

I have a map of type

`Map<String, List<String>>`

I want to sort the elements in each List. No need to sort the map, but, need to sort each list of the map i.e. sort the values independently. Hope I am clear.

I tried using keySet and entrySet elements on a Map, but, getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.ComparableTimSort.binarySort(ComparableTimSort.java:232)
    at java.util.ComparableTimSort.sort(ComparableTimSort.java:176)
    at java.util.ComparableTimSort.sort(ComparableTimSort.java:146)
    at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:472)
    at java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:155)
```

Looks like I am having `null` in the List I am trying to sort.

Is there any way to sort a List having null in it?

Comment: Not clear. Sort all the elements in all the list and add the result to a new list? Sort each list independently?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since list you want to sort can contain `null` and you can't call `compareTo` on `null` (since it doesn't have any methods nor fields) you will need to provide your own Comparator which will handle `null` and use it with sorting method.

For instance if you would like to place `null` at end of ascending order you will need to implement rules like:

- `null` `null` - don't swap, there is no point (return 0)
- `null` `"someString"` - swap, null is bigger and should be placed after `"someString"` (return 1)
- `"someString"` `null` - don't swap, first argument (`"someString"`) is smaller than `null` (return -1)
- `"string1"` `"string2"` - return default result of comparing both non-null values

and your Comparator can look like

```
Comparator<String> myComparator = new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
        if (s1==null && s2==null) return 0;//swapping has no point here
        if (s1==null) return  1;
        if (s2==null) return -1;
        return s1.compareTo(s2);
    }
};
```

Now you can use it

```
for (List<String> list : yourMap.values()) {
    Collections.sort(list, myComparator);
}
```

---

#### Java 8 update

Since Java 8 `Comparator` provides methods which can wrap other comparator and create another one which will place nulls at start or end of our collection. This methods are:

- `Comparator.nullsFirst(Comparator)`
- `Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator)`

Also `sort(Comparator)` method was added to `List` interface which means we don't need to call explicitly `Collections.sort(list,comparator)`.

So your code can look like:

```
for (List<String> list : yourMap.values()) {
    list.sort(Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.naturalOrder()));
}
```

But nothing stops you from using other comparator instead of `Comparator.naturalOrder()` like one stored in `String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER` which now can also be created with `String::compareToIgnoreCase` method reference.

Answer (score 3):

Iterate over map values and sort,

```
 for(List<String> e : map.values()){
    Collections.sort(e);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the `Map`'s keyset like this:

```
Map<String, List<String>> map;

for(String s : map.keySet()){
    Collections.sort(map.get(s));
}
```

Comment: Although it is correct, according to [Performance considerations for keySet() and entrySet() of Map](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3870064/performance-considerations-for-keyset-and-entryset-of-map), I'd use `entrySet` rather than `keySet`.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have your map like that:

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
map = putMyStuffInTheMap();
```

You should iterate the lists that you'd like to sort and just sort them:

```
Collection<List<String>> listsFromTheMap = map.values();    
for (List<String> listFromTheMap : listsFromTheMap) {
        Collections.sort(listFromTheMap);
}
```

And that's it. Hope it helps.