# How can I make anagram program code faster? (java)

Tags: java

I am a not so experienced programmer. I've written an anagram program and the only problem is that its not fast enough. I've been told that my nested `for loop` is the problem, but i can't figure how to fix it (`set1` is a `HashSet` with all the words I'm working on, map is a `LinkedHashMap<String, String>` and anagram a `TreeMap<String, TreeSet<String>>`):

```
for (String element : set1) {
    char[] woord = element.toCharArray(); //alfabetical order of each word
    Arrays.sort(woord);
    String chartostring = new String(woord);
    map.put(element, chartostring); // add each word with its sorted letters
    TreeSet<String> order_words = new TreeSet<String>(); //creating list of anagrams
    for (String o : map.keySet()) { //for each word
        if (map.get(o).equals(chartostring)) { //check if there is a value in map which is equal to the sorted letters
            order_words.add(o); //add word to list of anagrams
            if (order_words.size() > 1) { //we want anagrams so only print if there are atleast 2 words
                anagram.put(chartostring, order_words);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone please help me out? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5):

The nested loop is, indeed, slow, because you iterate a map as if it were a list. Wouldn't it be nice if you could replace the nested loop with a quick look-up in a hash map? Unfortunately, this is not an option when you deal with `Map<String,String>`, because multiple words will have identical sorted representation. That is why you built a map from a word to its sorted representation, not the other way around.

What this means, however, is that you can build a map from a sorted representation to a *list* of words:

```
Map<String,List<String>> sortedRepToWords
```

You can build this map in a single loop, before doing any matching. With this map-of-lists in place, you can eliminate the nested loop, replacing it with a look-up of the entire list from `sortedRepToWords`.

Comment: thanks for your comment, I will try it, I am a beginner so I dont know all the options.

Answer (score 2):

Introducing Java 8...

```
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.*;

Map<String, List<String>> tmp = set1.parallelStream() // Possibly using multiple cores...
    .collect(groupingBy(s-> sortMe(s))); // One liner!

List<List<String>> result = tmp.values().stream()
    .filter(l -> l.size() > 1)  // At least 2 anagrams
    .collect(toList());

System.out.println(tmp);
System.out.println(result);

//...//

// If you really want to use Java 8 for sorting a String...
private String sortMe(String input) {
    return Stream.of(input.split("")).sorted().collect(joining());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do this in order of 1 (single loop) if you use the HashSet.

```
Set<char[]> dict_set = new HashSet<char[]>();
Set<char[]> anag_set = new HashSet<char[]>();

for (String element : set1) {

 // Sort the characters in string.
 char[] woord= element.toCharArray();
 Arrays.sort(woord);

 //if already encountered add as a known anagram
 //else add the sorted charset to the dictionary.

 if (dict_set.contains(woord)) anag_set.add(woord)
 else dict_set.add(word);

 return anag_set;
}
```

Incase you need all the strings that are anagrams and its sortedform; you can use a map of sorted-form and a list of all associated anagrams.

PS : its just a psuedocode.

Comment: Since its a hashset -- look ups are very fast and you can do away with the foorloop.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this is better in your case, but when I need `key` and `value` of a `map` I use the `entrySet`. So the call of the `get` method is avoied and a part of time is saved ...

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3870210/1811730

```
for (String element : set1) {
    char[] woord = element.toCharArray(); //alfabetical order of each word
    Arrays.sort(woord);
    String chartostring = new String(woord);
    map.put(element, chartostring); // add each word with its sorted letters
    TreeSet<String> order_words = new TreeSet<String>(); //creating list of anagrams
    for (Entry o : map.entrySet()) { //for each word
        if (o.getValue().equals(chartostring)) { //check if there is a value in map which is equal to the sorted letters
            order_words.add(o.getKey()); //add word to list of anagrams
            if(order_words.size()>1){ //we want anagrams so only print if there are atleast 2 words
                  anagram.put(chartostring, order_words); 
              }
        }
    }
}
```

If it is not enough, I think you should rewrite your code with another logic and try to implement the answer of dasblinkenlight

Comment: should I replace this with my inner forloop or put it outside of it?

Comment: I dont understand your question, I have adapted your code for the example ... try to replace or put it outside.

Comment: omg sorry I see. Thanks! I will try and see if this actually solves the problem, because I will still have a nested for loop

Answer (score 0):

```
// Importing the Arrays class that will help us manipulate arrays.
import java.util.Arrays;

public class AnagramTest {

  private static boolean isAnagram(String str1 , String str2){
    // Converting both strings to char arrays as strings do not have direct
    // sorting method in java.
    char [] leftArray = ( str1.trim().toLowerCase()).toCharArray();
    char [] rightArray = ( str2.trim().toLowerCase()).toCharArray();
    Arrays.parallelSort(leftArray);
    Arrays.parallelSort(rightArray);

    if(leftArray.length != rightArray.length){
      return false;
    }
    // Both char arrays have the same number of characters
    for(int i = 0; i < leftArray.length; i++){
      if(leftArray[i] != rightArray[i]){
        return false;  
      }
    }
    // We only get to this stage if all the elements pass the if test
    return true;
  }

  public static void main(String [] args){
    String a = "integral"; // initializing first string
    String b = "Triangle"; // initializing second string
    System.out.println(isAnagram(a,b));     
  }         
}
```

Comment: This doesn't really solve the issue of finding anagrams based on in a list of words. It just compares if two strings are anagrams of each other.