# How to for each the hashmap?

Tags: java

I have this field:

```
HashMap<String, HashMap> selects = new HashMap<String, HashMap>();
```

For each `Hash<String, HashMap>` I need to create a `ComboBox`, whose items are the value (which happens to be a HashMap itself) of `HashMap <String, **HashMap**>`.

By way of (non-functioning) demonstration:

```
for (int i=0; i < selects.size(); i++) {
    HashMap h = selects[i].getValue();
    ComboBox cb = new ComboBox();

    for (int y=0; y < h.size(); i++) {
        cb.items.add(h[y].getValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: In Java 8 using Lambda : http://stackoverflow.com/a/25616206/1503859

Comment: Java 8 using streams : https://stackoverflow.com/a/32343195/1216775 , one advantage with streams is they can be parallelized as well.

Answer (score 1408, accepted):

I know I'm a bit late for that one, but I'll share what I did too, in case it helps someone else :

```
HashMap<String, HashMap> selects = new HashMap<String, HashMap>();

for(Map.Entry<String, HashMap> entry : selects.entrySet()) {
    String key = entry.getKey();
    HashMap value = entry.getValue();

    // do what you have to do here
    // In your case, another loop.
}
```

Comment: I never remember how to write this, so i always come back to this same answer. Upvoted, because this is clean answer and this code is copy pasted to so many places in my projects, thanks!

Comment: @Katu just write yourmap..entrySet().for and the IDE autocomplete will handle it.

Answer (score 295):

> **Lambda** Expression Java 8

In Java 1.8 (Java 8) this has become lot easier by using **forEach** method from Aggregate operations(**Stream operations**) that looks similar to iterators from **Iterable** Interface.

Just copy paste below statement to your code and rename the **HashMap** variable from **hm** to your HashMap variable to print out key-value pair.

```
HashMap<Integer,Integer> hm = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
/*
 *     Logic to put the Key,Value pair in your HashMap hm
 */

// Print the key value pair in one line.
hm.forEach((k,v) -> System.out.println("key: "+k+" value:"+v));
```

Here is an example where a **Lambda Expression** is used:

```
    HashMap<Integer,Integer> hm = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    Random rand = new Random(47);
    int i=0;
    while(i<5){
        i++;
        int key = rand.nextInt(20);
        int value = rand.nextInt(50);
        System.out.println("Inserting key: "+key+" Value: "+value);
        Integer imap =hm.put(key,value);
        if( imap == null){
            System.out.println("Inserted");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Replaced with "+imap);
        }               
    }

    hm.forEach((k,v) -> System.out.println("key: "+k+" value:"+v));

Output:

Inserting key: 18 Value: 5
Inserted
Inserting key: 13 Value: 11
Inserted
Inserting key: 1 Value: 29
Inserted
Inserting key: 8 Value: 0
Inserted
Inserting key: 2 Value: 7
Inserted
key: 1 value:29
key: 18 value:5
key: 2 value:7
key: 8 value:0
key: 13 value:11
```

Also one can use **Spliterator** for the same.

```
Spliterator sit = hm.entrySet().spliterator();
```

**UPDATE**

---

Including documentation links to Oracle Docs.
For more on **Lambda** go to this [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) and must read [Aggregate Operations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/) and for Spliterator go to this [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.html).

Comment: and I guess we cannot local variables inside enclosing scope without declaring them final. Got `Local variable schedule defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final` while using variable declared outside lambda body, unlike closures in groovy.

Comment: The downside to using lambdas is that you cannot return the other method, while inside the lambda.

Comment: What is use of spliterator here? Are you using parallel streams?

Comment: If you are working on android, forEach call mentioned here requires API level 24.

Answer (score 55):

`Map.values()`:

```
HashMap<String, HashMap<SomeInnerKeyType, String>> selects =
    new HashMap<String, HashMap<SomeInnerKeyType, String>>();

...

for(HashMap<SomeInnerKeyType, String> h : selects.values())
{
   ComboBox cb = new ComboBox();
   for(String s : h.values())
   {
      cb.items.add(s);
   }
}
```

Comment: +1: This is a neater approach than my answer (assuming we're using Java 5 or later)

Comment: Use of generic args on the outer HashMap would seem to indicate Java 5 or later.  [[ But I did wonder about what Java this was since the inner HashMap didn't have generic args and there was an array access done on a HashMap... but its just some "pseudo" code for conveying the question. ]]

Comment: Care to explain why it didn't seem to work for you? Are you using Java 5 or later? We're following your code example, which doesn't seem to do anything with the combo box once its created. Or are the values not in the order you want?  Or did you need the keys instead of the values in the combo box? I think most would agree that any of the 3 answers so far should work fine, so likely there's a problem with apply the answer or another problem somewhere else that we may be able to help with if you give us more info.

Comment: ooohh...i stupiding =). Only one question how get HashMap<this->String, HashMap<SomeInnerKeyType, String>>

Comment: @simply denis - I'm afraid I don't understand your question? Are you asking how do you get a reference to `HashMap<String, HashMap<SomeInnerKeyType, String>>`?  If your loop is in a method, you should be able to use `this.selects` or simply `selects`? Otherwise, you should pass the map in as a parameter to the method that contains the loop.  Or are you asking how to get a specific inner `HashMap<SomeInnerKeyType, String>` for a given key (`this->String`?) You would use `selects.get(keyString)`. If I'm completely misunderstanding, please clarify.

Comment: For a better answer, see Cyril N.'s answer below.

Answer (score 33):

### Streams Java 8

Along with `forEach` method that accepts a [lambda expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) we have also got [stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) APIs, in Java 8.

**Iterate over entries (Using forEach and Streams):**

```
sample.forEach((k,v) -> System.out.println(k + "=" + v)); 
sample.entrySet().stream().forEachOrdered((entry) -> {
            Object currentKey = entry.getKey();
            Object currentValue = entry.getValue();
            System.out.println(currentKey + "=" + currentValue);
        });
sample.entrySet().parallelStream().forEach((entry) -> {
            Object currentKey = entry.getKey();
            Object currentValue = entry.getValue();
            System.out.println(currentKey + "=" + currentValue);
        });
```

The advantage with streams is they can be parallelized easily and can be useful when we have multiple CPUs at disposal. We simply need to use `parallelStream()` in place of `stream()` above. With parallel streams it makes more sense to use `forEach` as `forEachOrdered` would make no difference in performance. If we want to iterate over keys we can use `sample.keySet()` and for values `sample.values()`.

**Why `forEachOrdered` and not `forEach` with streams ?**

Streams also provide `forEach` method but the behaviour of `forEach` is explicitly nondeterministic where as the `forEachOrdered` performs an action for each element of this stream, in the **encounter order of the stream** if the stream has a defined encounter order. So `forEach` does not guarantee that the order would be kept. Also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32797579/foreach-vs-foreachordered-in-java-8-stream) for more.

Answer (score 23):

You can iterate over a `HashMap` (and many other collections) using an iterator, e.g.:

```
HashMap<T,U> map = new HashMap<T,U>();

...

Iterator it = map.values().iterator();

while (it.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(it.next());
}
```

Comment: I can not with such a design down to the level below

Comment: @Yes, you can.  You can create an inner iterator based on `it.next()`.

Answer (score 15):

I generally do the same as cx42net, but I don't explicitly create an Entry.

```
HashMap<String, HashMap> selects = new HashMap<String, HashMap>();
for (String key : selects.keySet())
{
    HashMap<innerKey, String> boxHolder = selects.get(key);
    ComboBox cb = new ComboBox();
    for (InnerKey innerKey : boxHolder.keySet())
    {
        cb.items.add(boxHolder.get(innerKey));
    }
}
```

This just seems the most intuitive to me, I think I'm prejudiced against iterating over the values of a map.

Comment: If you're iterating over the whole map, don't do lookups. Each hash look up may be O(1), but now you're doing n*O(1) of them for O(N) when the total number of hash lookups you need is 0.

Answer (score 10):

Use `entrySet`,

```
/**
 *Output: 
D: 99.22
A: 3434.34
C: 1378.0
B: 123.22
E: -19.08

B's new balance: 1123.22
 */

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

public class MainClass {
  public static void main(String args[]) {

    HashMap<String, Double> hm = new HashMap<String, Double>();

    hm.put("A", new Double(3434.34));
    hm.put("B", new Double(123.22));
    hm.put("C", new Double(1378.00));
    hm.put("D", new Double(99.22));
    hm.put("E", new Double(-19.08));

    Set<Map.Entry<String, Double>> set = hm.entrySet();

    for (Map.Entry<String, Double> me : set) {
      System.out.print(me.getKey() + ": ");
      System.out.println(me.getValue());
    }

    System.out.println();

    double balance = hm.get("B");
    hm.put("B", balance + 1000);

    System.out.println("B's new balance: " + hm.get("B"));
  }
}
```

see complete example here:

- http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/java.util/HashMapentrySet.htm

Comment: It definitively works, I use it every day :) What exactly doesn't work? As you have `HashMap<String, HashMap>`, you would need two loops - one for the outer and one for the inner HashMap. Btw - you should definitively type the second HashMap - don't know what you store in it, but something like HashMap<String, HashMap<string, String>> - though, from your example, it seems you should use `HashMap<String, Set<String>>`. And another thing - use interfaces: `Map<String, Map>` when you can.