# Parallel For Loop java has race condition

Tags: java, parallel-processing

I have a piece of code that runs in a loop that I would like to parallelize.
The use of ExecutorService makes the code very fast but I am getting inconsistent results, possibly due to a race condition. Is there another parallel for loop that works fast like this one and is always consistent?

```
ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(8);

    try{
        for (String tour : tours)
            {
                if (valid)
                {
                   exec.submit(() ->
                     {
                        double len1 = tsp.tourLen(tour, cities); //expensive sequentially
                        if (bestLen == -1 || len1 < bestLen)
                        {
                            bestLen = len1;
                            bestTour = tour;
                        }
                    });
                }
            }

            System.out.println("\n     Best tour len: " + bestLen);
            System.out.println("\n          Best tour: " + bestTour);

        } finally
        {
            exec.shutdown();
        }
```

Comment: Isn't there supposed to be a `exec.submit()` call in there somewhere?

Comment: Not sure why that didn't copy in- added (thank you)

Comment: are `bestLen` and `bestTour` using `synchronized`?

Comment: no, can you please show me how would this be implemented?

Comment: see answer below, I would assume your functions results are not coming in in order.

Comment: but just in case, http://winterbe.com/posts/2015/04/30/java8-concurrency-tutorial-synchronized-locks-examples/

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do this is do the heavy processing in the background thread, load that into a `HashMap<String, Double>`, to avoid concurrency issues. 
(tour, len1)

Then iterate over that map, with a foreach lambda `hashmap.foreach((k,v) -> /*comparison here*/);`

**Note:**

Though I mentioned synchronized above ,for this issue I doubt it will help, because, **You can't do comparisons on data you do not have yet.**

source:
[How to for each the hashmap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4234985/how-to-for-each-the-hashmap/25616206#25616206)