# Modifying member of object in Map

Tags: java, collections

If i create a class that has a member variable called "testName", and then create a few objects from this and place them all as values in a "Map". How can i iterate through this Map and modify the "testName" variable in each value Object?

In other words how can i access & modify members of an Object when that object has been placed in a Map.

Comment: Also see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066589/java-iterate-through-hashmap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the objects you want modified are all values in the map, and you don't want to change the mappings from key to value, you can iterate through a collection of just the map's values:

```
Collection< ValueType > vals = map.values();
for (ValueType val : vals) {
    val.testName = ...
}
```

Comment: This put me in the right direction. i have also discovered that you can apparently modify members by doing: 
    testmap.get("foo").testName = "new value";

Answer (score 2):

You have to **iterate** through each of the entries of the Map and modify the name. [See here for example](http://jtoee.blogspot.com/2008/05/better-way-to-iterate-java-maps.html) on how to iterate through the Map

Answer (score 1):

A Map is not by itself iterable, but you can get the keySet from the map via the keySet() method and since this is a Set is iterable (implements the Iterable interface).  Iterate through the keySet obtaining each value from the Map via its get method and make the changes you desire.