# A question mark within a @PathVariable in Spring MVC?

Tags: spring-mvc, path-variables

Within the `@Controller` of a search engine:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/search/{query}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String search(@PathVariable String query) {}
```

If a user wants to search `/search/w?rld` (which should match world, warld, whrld, etc.), the variable `query` equals `w`, because of the question mark which indicated a GET var.

I tried `"/search/{query:.+}"`, but still doesn't work.

Any idea how to solve that problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is not in the Spring configuration. It's in the URL. The question mark is the symbol indicating the start of the query String. If it's part of the URL, it must be encoded:

```
/search/w%3Frld
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want a user to be able to write his query directly within an URL in his browser, without that he has to manually escape the question marks himself.

Comment: Then learn him to escape the question mark, because there's no way around it.

Answer (score 0):

if it is just for one method :

[Spring MVC - How to get all request params in a map in Spring controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7312436/spring-mvc-how-to-get-all-request-params-in-a-map-in-spring-controller)

add WebRequest  req to your signature method 
then 
Map parameters = req.getParameterMap();