# Spring @RestController how to get header at class level

Tags: java, spring, rest

I know I can get a header via method parameters via the `@RequestHeader` annotation as shown in this answer [How to get access to HTTP header information in Spring MVC REST controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19556039/how-to-get-access-to-http-header-information-in-spring-mvc-rest-controller); however, if I am using the same header for ever single method, this will get tedious. I am looking how to get the header information from a private utility method; not a http exposed method

I would like to do something like this:

```
@RestController
public class MyController {

     private Identity getIdentity(){
         Token token = ParseToken(headers.get("Authorization"));
         token.verify("secret");
         return new User(token.name);
         ...
```

Is something like this possible? Or am I barking up the wrong tree altogether?

Comment: @Deadpool not a duplicate. I specifically said I knew I could get this information by passing it into the method via the RequestHeader annoation as in the link you posed; I want to do it a different way

Comment: It is a duplicate, see some of the other answers that show how to get the `HttpHeaders` object instead of a specific header. There are no other solutions that I'm aware of.

Comment: Every single answer required passing the headers in through the http methods

Comment: Probably You can achieve it using Handler Interceptors.

Comment: How did you solved this problem @TheCatWhisperer?