# Why does my @RequestHeader not pass values?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I am working on springwebmvc REST API as a task in my internship. I have a problem where I can't pass values using my Http Header. I'm trying to authenticate using username and password and authdto values are not getting initialized in my app.

Method:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/{username}")
    @ApiOperation(value = "fetch Trainee", response = TraineeResponseDTO.class)
    @ApiResponses(value = {
            @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Successfully fetched a trainee"),
            @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "Application failed to process the request")
    })
    public ResponseEntity<TraineeResponseDTO> getTrainee(@PathVariable String username,
                                                         @RequestHeader(value = "Auth-Username") String authUsername,
                                                         @RequestHeader(value = "Auth-Password") String authPassword) {
        traineeValidation.validateUsernameNotNull(username);
        AuthDTO authDTO = new AuthDTO(authUsername, authPassword);
        TraineeEntity trainee = traineeService.findByUsername(authDTO, username);
        TraineeResponseDTO responseDTO = traineeConverter.convertModelToResponse(trainee);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(responseDTO, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'jacoco'
    id "org.sonarqube" version "4.4.1.3373"
    id 'war'
}

group = 'com.nikolabojanic'

java {
    sourceCompatibility = '17'
}

sonar {
    properties {
        property "sonar.projectKey", "spring-rest"
        property "sonar.projectName", "spring-rest"
        property "sonar.host.url", "http://localhost:9002"
        property "sonar.token", ""
        property "sonar.jacoco.reportPaths", "build/reports/jacoco/test/jacocoTestReport.xml"
        property "sonar.login", "admin"
        property "sonar.password", "sonar"
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:6.4.0.Final'
    implementation 'org.springframework:spring-orm:6.1.1'
    implementation 'org.postgresql:postgresql:42.7.1'
    implementation 'org.springframework:spring-webmvc:6.1.2'
    implementation 'org.springframework:spring-web:6.1.2'
    implementation 'jakarta.servlet:jakarta.servlet-api:6.0.0'
    implementation 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:4.0.1'
    implementation 'javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.3.2'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.16.0'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.16.0'
    implementation 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:3.0.0'
    implementation 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:3.0.0'
    implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.32'
    implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.7.32'
    implementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.10.1'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.30'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.30'
    testCompileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.30'
    testAnnotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.30'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework:spring-test:6.1.0'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.10.1'
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:5.7.0'
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:5.7.0'
    testImplementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.14.0'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    finalizedBy jacocoTestReport
}

jacocoTestReport {
    dependsOn test
    reports {
        xml.required = true
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQeYb.png)
I hard-coded the same username and password values from the header to initialize my authDTO in the application, and my authentication logic is working fine. I think the problem is that I'm not reading values from header at all.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try write `@RequestHeader("Auth-Username")` instead of `@RequestHeader(value = "Auth-Username")`?

Probably it may helps.

Also look at [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19556039/how-to-get-access-to-http-header-information-in-spring-mvc-rest-controller), perhaps it may by useful.

Answer (score 0):

as per the [spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/web/webflux/controller/ann-methods/requestheader.html):
you can write the Request header annotation like this:

```
public ResponseEntity<TraineeResponseDTO> getTrainee(@PathVariable String username,
                                                         @RequestHeader("Auth-Username") String authUsername,
                                                         @RequestHeader("Auth-Password") String authPassword) {
```

it will solve the issue. Happy Coding...!! :)