# spring can't instantiate UriInfo in rest service

Tags: rest, spring-boot, jax-rs

I try to use UriInfo  to get the list of request parameters, here is my code :

```
@RestController public class MyController {
@RequestMapping(value = "/documents", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public Object getDocuments( @Context UriInfo uriInfo,  
 @RequestParam(value    = "sta", required = false) String param1,      @RequestParam(value = "sta2", required   = false) String param2){

  MultivaluedMap<String, String> queryParamList = uriInfo.getQueryParameters();

}
```

this code cause this exception : 
org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo]: Specified class is an interface

thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `UriInfo` isn't a Spring MVC object. It is a JAX-RS object and you are not using JAX-RS, you're using Spring MVC. With Spring MVC, if you just want the parameter map, you can just inject it with `@RequestParam`

```
public Object getDocuments(@RequestParam MultiValueMap<String, String> requestParams)
```

Note, the `MultiValueMap` is a Spring class, it's not the JAX-RS `MultivaluedMap`.

**See also:**

- [Spring MVC - How to get all request params in a map in Spring controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7312436/2587435)