# Java Spring Map<String, Set<String>> as RequestParameter

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot

I'm comming from the .net world, where if you have an argument like a `Dictionary<string,List<string>> foo` in the query string, you can do something like `foo[one][0]=OneZero,foo[two][0]=TwoZero,foo[two][1]=TwoOne` etc. I'd like to have the same in Java Spring (springboot).

I guess the data-type I'm looking for would be either `HashMap<String,HashSet<String>>` or `Map<String,Set<String>>`. However I was unable to find a proper solution for this problem. I did managed to make `List<String> foo` work with `foo=one&foo=two` or `foo=one,two` but it seems that using a `Map` as an argument is unsupported. Is my understanding correct? Is there no out of the box solution for using Maps/Dictionaries (let alone nested ones) as request parameters?

**Code**

```
@RestController
public class MyController {

    @GetMapping(value = "/search")
    public PLPResponse getStuff(@RequestParam Optional<String> name, @RequestParam Optional<Map<String,Set<String>> foo, HttpServletRequest request) {
    //magic happens here
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you use a json payload or only URL parameters ?

Comment: How would `foo[two][1]=TwoOne` map into a `Map<String,Set<String>>`? Assuming you use `@RequestParam("foo")`, I can see `"two"` being the map key, and `"TwoOne"` being the set value, but what is `"1"` supposed to be? An array index? If so, shouldn't that me mapped into a `Map<String,String[]>`? Or a `Map<String,List<String>>`, where the index value has meaning? It would be inappropriate to map it into a `Set` like you say, since sets are **unordered**.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7312436/spring-mvc-how-to-get-all-request-params-in-a-map-in-spring-controller

Comment: @Marged only url query strings are acceptable

Comment: @ChrisBelyeu not a duplicate. I am looking for a specific parameter, not all the query strings. Also note the Set/List in my question

Comment: @Andreas As you can see my example was for a List. (your assumptions are all correct). I don't care about the order but if this is only feasible with a list, like in C# I will be okay.

Comment: Does annotating a method parameter with [`@RequestParam`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestParam.html) and using a [`MultiValueMap<String, String>`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/MultiValueMap.html) as its type solve your problem?

Comment: I think you might be able to do this by applying your own `WebDataBinder`. See: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-initbinder

Comment: @caco3 And how would you use it precisely? Because if I set the type, and try to invoke the method, it throws an error, saying ```No primary or default constructor found for interface org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap```

Comment: Can you share the code of your controller?

Comment: @caco3 updated post with a sample

Comment: Try removing `Optional`: `public PLPResponse getStuff(@RequestParam Optional<String> name, @RequestParam Map<String,Set<String>> foo, HttpServletRequest request)`. It should wire all parameters into `foo`, but I'm still not sure that it is exactly what you're trying to achieve

Comment: @caco3 But that's just it. I don't want ALL the parameters in ```foo```. My query has a static part (like filtering by "name") and a dynamic part (let's say by color or by size, or by whatever dynamic attribute is in there). And that dynamic part is - by nature - something which should be collected into a ```Map<String, Set<String>>``` or something similar.

Comment: @Andreas any chance you can share some sample code which works with a ```@RestController```?

Comment: @Hegi I don't have any code, hence the "I think..."