# How to get the name and value of a parameter using RequestParam?

Tags: java, spring

I want to get the name and value of a URL parameter using RequestMapping.

For instance, if I pass in the URL 
http://localhost:8080/assignment2/trafficcameras?ip_comm_status=bad

I want to isolate the name of the parameter as "ip_comm_status".

And the value of the parameter as "bad".

How would I access the name and value of any parameter pair?

The problem is that I know how to get the value but not the name of a parameter.

ip_comm_status and camera_status are my valid parameter names.

So far I have:

```
    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/trafficcameras", params = {"ip_comm_status", "camera_status"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String parseParams(@RequestParam(value = "ip_comm_status", required = false) String ip_comm_status_val,
            @RequestParam(value = "camera_status", required = false) String camera_status_val) {


    }
```

Comment: Probably this is what you are looking for...
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18489124/2140633

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `Map<String, String>` to get all [request param](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestParam.html) names and values

**If the method parameter is `Map<String, String>` or `MultiValueMap<String, String>` and a parameter name is not specified, then the map parameter is populated with all request parameter names and values.**

Here is an example from [baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-request-param)

> We can also have multiple parameters without defining their names or count by just using Map

```
@PostMapping("/api/foos")
@ResponseBody
public String updateFoos(@RequestParam Map<String,String> allParams) {
    return "Parameters are " + allParams.entrySet();
}
```

Which will then reflect back any parameters sent

```
curl -X POST -F 'name=abc' -F 'id=123' http://localhost:8080/api/foos
-----
Parameters are {[name=abc], [id=123]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look up @PathVariable.

```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/ex/foos/{id}", method = GET)
   @ResponseBody
   public String getFoosBySimplePathWithPathVariable(
   @PathVariable("id") long id) {
    return "Get a specific Foo with id=" + id;
}
```

Comment: Add more flesh to make the OP understand what you mean by "Look up @PathVariable."

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I think you are miss placing value in `@RequestParam` attribute.

```
@ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/trafficcameras", params = {"ip_comm_status", "camera_status"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String parseParams(@RequestParam(name = "ip_comm_status", required = false) String ip_comm_status_val,
            @RequestParam(name = "camera_status", required = false) String camera_status_val) {


    }
```

and you are not confusing it with defaultValue,(this value will be used in case no value is passed) of RequestParam i.e `(@RequestParam(defaultValue='xx'))`