# Is which the best request parameter mapping strategy in Spring Framework?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am Java web developer, usually develop Spring MVC.

I have been using @RequestMapping or @RequestParam for mapping to hashMap at Controller.

It is a terrible way. I should always cast type when using value.

But nowadays I try to use @ModelAttribute to write clean code at Controller.

However, there are some problem.

**case 1) make DTO for each EndPoint.**

We can make DTO for each EndPoint, but DTO will have many duplicated property.

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
class GetUserInfoDTO {
   private String id;
   private String name;
}


@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
class PostUserInfoDTO {
   private String name;
   private Integer age;
   private String address;
   private String gender;
   private String email;
   private Date joinDate;
}
```

in controller,

```
@GetMapping("/user")
public ResultDTO getUserInfo (@ModelAttribute GetUserInfoDTO){
    ...
     return ResultDTO;
}

@PostMapping("/user")
public ResultDTO postUserInfo (@ModelAttribute PostUserInfoDTO){
    ...
     return ResultDTO;
}
```

In this case, we can apply independent validation strategy for each End-Point.

for example..

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
class GetUserInfoDTO {
   @NotNull
   private String id;
   private String name;
}


@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
class PostUserInfoDTO {

   @NotNull
   private String name;
   @NotNull
   private Integer age;
   @NotEmpty
   private String address;
   private String gender;
   private String email;
   private Date joinDate;
}
```

like this.

But so many model classes made, and so many duplicated property exists.

**case 2. make common DTO for each Controller.**

We can make DTO for each Controller, and reuse them.

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
class UserInfoDTO {
   private String id;
   private String name;
   private Integer age;
   private String address;
   private String gender;
   private String email;
   private Date joinDate;
}


@GetMapping("/user")
public ResultDTO getUserInfo (@ModelAttribute UserInfoDTO){
    //I want only id, name
    ...
     return ResultDTO;
}

@PostMapping("/user")
public ResultDTO postUserInfo (@ModelAttribute UserInfoDTO){
    ...
     return ResultDTO;
}
```

But In this case, we can only pass specific properties.

If someone send other parameter than id and name, we can't notice. ( 400 error not occur )

Code assistance can't recommend us specific properties that use at single end-point.

I don't like these cases.

In first case, I should make so many models and It's management will be so hard.

Second case, unnecessary properties exists and it hard to validate for each end-point.

Which way is the best?

Or Can you recommend another way for mapping request parameter to model object?

Comment: We can get all the parameters and values as a map instance. Please check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60304941/4214241) . This method would require explicit code to populate the model object

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37386758/is-it-bad-to-create-different-classes-for-rest-request-and-response