# Rejecting GET requests with additional query params

Tags: java, spring-boot, http, spring-mvc

I have an HTTP GET endpoint that accepts some query parameters:

```
@GetMapping("/cat")
public ResponseEntity<Cat> getCat(@RequestParam("catName") String catName){ ...
```

If the clients will send additional query parameters, the endpoint will ignore them.

```
GET .../cat?catName=Oscar                Getting Oscar
GET .../cat?catName=Oscar&gender=male    Getting Oscar
GET .../cat?catName=Oscar&x=y            Getting Oscar
```

I want to **reject** HTTP requests that will send additional query parameters:

```
GET .../cat?catName=Oscar                OK
GET .../cat?catName=Oscar&gender=male    Reject (HTTP error code XYZ)
GET .../cat?catName=Oscar&x=y            Reject (HTTP error code XYZ)
```

I can change the signature of the method to accept a map and validate the values in the map as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18489124/5458827).

Is there a way to do with while keeping the cleaner and self explained method signature?

Comment: If you put in your controller method the annotation @RequestParam and the proper field, every request which have more or different param will rejected. I think you don't need do nothing except, if you want a custom exception you can create one and send a specific code error for that situation.

Comment: You can also create other methods with unacceptable params and return your custom error code in those methods.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to implement a `HandlerInterceptor` and validate such rule in `preHandle()`. If the request contains the query parameters that does not defined in the controller method , you just throw a specific type of `Exception` and configure a `@ControllerAdvice` to handle this exception. Something like :

```java
public class FooHandlerInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler)
            throws Exception {

        if (handler instanceof HandlerMethod) {
            HandlerMethod hm = (HandlerMethod) handler;

            Set<String> allowQueryParams = Stream.of(hm.getMethodParameters())
                    .map(p -> p.getParameterAnnotation(RequestParam.class))
                    .map(req -> req.value())
                    .collect(toSet());

            for (String currentRequestParamName : request.getParameterMap().keySet()) {
                if (!allowQueryParams.contains(currentRequestParamName)) {
                    throw new FooRestException();
                }
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

And the `@ControllerAdvice` to handle the Exception :

```java
@ControllerAdvice
public class FooExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(FooRestException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handle(FooRestException ex) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>("Some query parameter are not defined", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

Finally register `FooHandlerInterceptor` to use it :

```java
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(new FooHandlerInterceptor());
    }
}
```

I just show you the idea. You can further tweak the codes in `HandlerInterceptor` if you want such checking is only applied to a particular controller method.

Comment: Tried following your approach but in line '.map(req -> req.value())'
here "req" is always null even if there is a post method which accepts a @valid object.