# how can I do to make it return error when restful url has invalid parameter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, restful-url

```
@RestController()   
@RequestMapping(path = "/users") 

public class UserController {     

    @GetMapping()     

    public @ResponseBody  Page<User> getAllUsers(@RequestParam Integer pageSize, UserRequest userRequest) {
      //TODO: some implementation
}}

public class UserRequest{

    public String name;

    public String age;

}
```

send the request with invalid parameter, like `localhost:8800/users?`**`name1`**`=1234`, I want to return error.  but  in fact it ignore the invalid parameter **name1.**

I tried to add the user defined annotation on the method parameter and on the class , codes like below

```
@RestController() 
@RequestMapping(path = "/users")

@Validated

public class UserController {

    @GetMapping()     
    
    public @ResponseBody  Page<User> getAllUsers(@RequestParam @Validated Integer pageSize, @Validated UserRequest userRequest} {
    
      //TODO: some implementation
    }
}
```

But it does not working.

I think  it is happened because framework has ignore the invalid parameter before the method was called.

where did framework handle the url and how can I do to make it return error instead of ignore?

Answer (score 0):

You can reject parameters that are not valid. You can do so in a [`HandlerInterceptor`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerInterceptor.html) class.

Reference: [Rejecting GET requests with additional query params](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70942039/13695861)

In addition to what is done in the above reference, in your `addInterceptors`, you can specify the path that is intercepted.

Like this:

```java
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    private String USERS_PATH = "/users";
    
    // If you want to cover all endpoints in your controller
    // private String USERS_PATH = List.of("/users", "/users/**");

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(new FooHandlerInterceptor()).addPathPatterns(USERS_PATH);
    }
}
```