# how to iterate through all the Employee objects contained in this treeMap and print it out to the screen?

Tags: java, object, loops, treemap

Thanks for taking the time to look at my question.

I am using a Tree map to add data into my system

private static  Map  employeeMap = new TreeMap();

I have then created employee objects like so

```
theEmployee = new Employee(randomIDno,fName, sName, gender, dPayLevel);
```

I then add it to the tree map like this

```
employeeMap.put(randomIDno,theEmployee);
```

I would just like to know how to  iterate through all the Employee objects contained in this treeMap and print it out to the screen?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066589/java-iterate-through-hashmap

(And tons of others.)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about order or the TreeMap is maintaining order for you, it's quite simple to use the [`values()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#values%28%29) method:

```
for(Employee employee : employeeMap.values()) {
  System.out.println(employee);
}
```

Comment: Thanks!! Yes the treeMap should be keeping order for me anyway.

Comment: and If I wanted to change an ovjects name or last name would I go
for(Employee employee : employeeMap.values()) {
employee.setname(value)

Comment: Yes, if your `Employee` object is mutable that is what you would use.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Iterator in java

```
Set s = employeeMap.entrySet();
Iterator i = s.iterator();

while (i.hasNext())
{
    // display each item.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you need to `sort` the elements in a different order than the default one. Override the `equals()` method for the object or provide a `Comparator` in the constructor