# How to get content of HashMap and displat it on Android?

Tags: java, android, arrays, hashmap

I have this :

```
HashMap<String, String[]> strs = new HashMap<String, String[]>(); 
String [] morning_food = new String [8];
String [] snack1_food = new String [6];
String [] lunch_food = new String [12];
String [] snack2_food = new String [4];
String [] nite_food = new String [10];

strs.put("Breakfast", morning_food);
strs.put("Snack1", snack1_food);
strs.put("Lunch", lunch_food);
strs.put("Snack2", snack2_food);
strs.put("Dinner", nite_food);
```

How to get the content of strs? I want to print out or display it into Log. Thx

Comment: I see this questions lacks research, because data from a `HashMap` can be retrieved with a key, which is the first parameter of the put method, and you use the get method with the key value to retrieve data...

Comment: [This has been answered elsewhere](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066589/java-iterate-through-hashmap/1066607#1066607)

Comment: mine is String [], the object is array, it is different problem should be >_<

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strs.toString()` ?

OR

You can:

```
for (String[] vals : strs.values()) {
    for (String val : vals) {
        System.out.print(val);
    }
}
```

Comment: both of them, it is not display the content of String [] morning_food = new String [8];
String [] snack1_food = new String [6];
String [] lunch_food = new String [12];
String [] snack2_food = new String [4];
String [] nite_food = new String [10];

Answer (score 0):

`strs.toString()` will return the content of the map as a String. It will delegate to the default `toString` of the arrays, which won't print anything useful, though. So you should use a List instead of a String[] as the value type of the map:

```
Map<String, List<String>> strs = new HashMap<String, List<String>>(); 
strs.put("Breakfast", new ArrayList<String>());
...
```

Collections should generally be preferred over arrays, in most of the cases.

Comment: so where I should put this 

String [] morning_food = new String [8];
String [] snack1_food = new String [6];
String [] lunch_food = new String [12];
String [] snack2_food = new String [4];
String [] nite_food = new String [10];


so they are relating ?

Comment: You don't put it anywhere. A list has a dynamic size. Once you add something to it, its size will automatically be incremented. Read the javadoc: it's a core class that must be known.

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] str-new String[strs.size()];
Set set=strs.keySet();
for(int i=0;i<strs.size();i++){
str[i]=strs.get(set.get(i));
}
```

Here **str** array will contain all the values.else you can directly use **strs.get(set.get(i))**.