# Using JSTL how to "put" a value into a HashMap

Tags: java, jstl

I'm looking to set the key value pairing of a HashMap using JSTL only. Is this possible?

I know how to retrieve the key value pairs, but I haven't found a way to set them.

Any help would be appreciated.

Example of retrieving HashMap key/value pairs using JSTL:

```
<c:forEach var="hash" items="${myHashMap}">             
    <c:out value="${hash.key}" />
    <c:out value="${hash.value}" />
...
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use the [`<c:set>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/set.html).

```html
<c:set target="${myHashMap}" property="key" value="value"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use JSTL to do that, but straight-up JSP will get it done...

```
<%
myHashMap.put("hello", "world");
%>
```

Comment: Ooh.  The evanwong answer is more JSTL-y, but I like straight-up JSP.

Comment: 1) You are not answering the concrete question (exclusively using JSTL). 2) The code example in your answer is incomplete. 3) scriptlets are [discouraged](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/code-convention-138726.html) since a decade. This was not a hate. The answer is simply not useful (as the downvote tooltip says). By the way, were you lying [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8682774/157882) where you said to not care about downvotes? :) You get sympathy upvotes soon enough.

Comment: @BalusC  I strongly disagree. JSTL does not exclude old school scriptlet, it absolutely works with it.  My example is complete and works within the context of the question which sounds, to me, as a useful solution.  It event takes less code and would make it through a refactoring.  The downvote for a working solution surprised me.  The "hate" comment was to keep the air light.  I guess I failed.