# Java project related suggestion

Tags: java

I am creating a project in java. I have collected a source code.In a class there is a problem I can't understand. My code is:

```
import static java.lang.reflect.Array.set;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeMap;

class treemapcl{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        TreeMap tm=new TreeMap();
        tm.put("Ravi",new Double(345.35));
        tm.put("Raju",new Double(12.45));
        tm.put("Ram",new Double(90.25));

        Set s=tm.entrySet();
        Iterator i=set.iterator();

        while(i.hasNext()){
            Map.Entry m=(Map.Entry)i.next();
            System.out.print(m.getKey()+" ");
            System.out.println(m.getValue());
        }

        System.out.println();   
        double d=((Double)tm.get("Ravi")).doubleValue();
        tm.put("Ravi",new Double(d+100));
        System.out.println("new value of Ravi:"+tm.get("Ravi"));
    }
}
```

I am getting error in the line :

```
Iterator i=set.iterator();
```

It says

> can't find symbol "set"

I am using Netbeans. What can I do to remove this error??

Comment: perhaps that why he sees a doctor, to know what is the symptoms

Comment: This post may help you [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8689725/map-entry-how-to-use-it][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8689725/map-entry-how-to-use-it

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at your decleration...

```
Set s=tm.entrySet();
    ^------------------
```

Then you use...

```
Iterator i=set.iterator();
           ^^^----------------
```

Try changing `Set s=tm.entrySet();` to `Set set=tm.entrySet();`

I'd also recommend that you take a look at and use [Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html)

Comment: Really? Why would this attract a down vote? If I've done something wrong, please educate me so I can fix it and learn from it

Answer (score 3):

In your code 
    `Iterator i=set.iterator();` the variable `set` is not defined, so make it

`Iterator i=s.iterator();` and it will work.