# what is the reason behind the interface Map have inner interface Entry?

Tags: java

I am going through how java classes and interfaces designed , just saw the `java/util/Map.java` and i got below doubt ?
please help me by answering.

what is the reason behind the interface `Map` have inner interface `Entry`?
Please see the source code of the java/util/Map.java and answer.

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8689757/1715829

Comment: Buddy this is not duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Map<K,V>` can be viewed as an associative storage (i.e. a container that connects keys to their values). It can also be viewed as a collection of pairs, where the first element is the key, and the second element is its corresponding value.

The majority of methods in `Map<K,V>` supports the associative container view of the map. `Map.Entry<K,V>` interface is there to support the other view of the map - i.e. as a collection of key-value pairs.

Each map provides access to so called *entry set*, which is a set of pairs from the map. Each pair is represented by an *instance* of `Map.Entry<K,V>`.

```
Map<Integer,String> myMap = ...
for (Map.Entry<Integer,String> e : myMap.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(e.getKey()+" ---> "+e.getValue());
}
```

One could have defined `MapEntry<K,V>` interface outside `Map<K,V>`. However, since the interface is very closely related to the map, a decision to nest the interface inside the map makes perfect sense.

Comment: As per my understanding based on your explanation , since it is very closely related to the map so defined inside the interface. am i right ?thank you for answering.

Comment: Upvote for recognizing what was done well in original JDK. I shall not speak of the abominations.

Comment: @NarayanaSai Yes, that's right. There is no exact measure for how closely should be that "closely related" thing, but a rule of thumb is that if a class or interface makes sense only in the context of another class or interface (e.g. map entries require a map of which they are entries) then it should probably be a nested class or interface.