# How to get value stored in ArrayList<HashMap<key,value>>?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, hashmap

I have  ArrayList>. In another activity I want to access all values stored in ArrayList>.

I have tried following code:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

for(Hashmap<String, String> map: mylist) {
    for(Entry<String, String> mapEntry: map) {
        String key = mapEntry.getKey();
        String value = mapEntry.getValue();
    }
}
```

but it shows an error at `for(Entry<String, String> mapEntry: map)` that it only interate over Array.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your code has bit different for this line,

```
for(Entry<String, String> mapEntry: map.entrySet())
```

Try this and let me know what happen,

```
for (HashMap<String, String> map : mylist)
     for (Entry<String, String> mapEntry : map.entrySet())
        {
        String key = mapEntry.getKey();
        String value = mapEntry.getValue();
        }
```

Answer (score 5):

## Simple way

Try this i hope it works for u also...

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> arraylist;
for (int i=0;i<arraylist.size();i++)
    {
        HashMap<String, String> hashmap= arraylist.get(i);
        String string= hashmap.get("Your_Key_Name");
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
       for(HashMap<String,String> map:myList){
           for(String str:map.keySet()){
              String key=str;
              String value=map.get(str);
           }
       }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    for(HashMap<String, String> map: mylist) {
        for(Entry<String, String> mapEntry: map.entrySet()) {
            String key = mapEntry.getKey();
            String value = mapEntry.getValue();
        }
    }
```

Note the line that says `for(Entry<String, String> mapEntry: map.entrySet())`

Answer (score 2):

According to this thread : [Iterate through a HashMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066589/java-iterate-through-hashmap) you have to use `HashMap.entrySet()` method.

You can take a look here too : http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/HashMap.html