# Java how to iterate Map<String, Device>

Tags: java, iterator

I have a custom Map using  where Device is an instance of my class named Device.

```
devices = new HashMap<String, Device>();
```

I tried several Iterators and for loops suggested at StackOverflow, but all of them seem to produce errors and I don't know why.

Example errors:

[image]

and

[image]

Comment: What is the error you are getting? as well as posting the code you have tried may help too.

Comment: Here's a method, that has worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066589/java-iterate-through-hashmap

Comment: I added screenshots of the errors

Comment: For your second example, you need to cast : `Device device = (Device) pairs.getValue();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the declaration of `devices` is incorrect. It should be:

```
Map<String, Device> devices;
```

Not the raw ("erased") type, `Map`. Modern compilers should give you warnings for using raw types. Take note of compiler warnings.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
HashMap<String, Device> devices = new HashMap<String, Device>();

// do stuff to load devices

Device currentDevice;
for (String key : devices.keySet()) {

    currentDevice = devices.get(key);
    // do stuff with current device

}
```

Comment: This is the cleanest way to iterate a hash map while keeping track of the key.

Answer (score 0):

In the first scenario, you just give

for(Map.Entry entry:devices.entrySet()){}

is only enough and you dont need to cast Map.Entry(String,Device) there.  In the second scenario, when you get the value from entry, it returns Object value, so you need to cast to your particular instance.So you have to give

Device device=(Device) pairs.getValue()

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 ways you can Iterate over a map
1)Iterating over entries using For-Each loop.
2)Iterating over keys or values using For-Each loop.
3) Iterating using Iterator. (for this you can iterate using Generics or without Generics)

```
    Map map = new HashMap();
Iterator entries = map.entrySet().iterator();
while (entries.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry) entries.next();
    Integer key = (Integer)entry.getKey();
    Integer value = (Integer)entry.getValue();
    System.out.println("Key = " + key + ", Value = " + value);
}
```