# Java - going through a hash map

Tags: java, while-loop, hashmap, enumeration, concurrenthashmap

I am in the process of updating some old Java code I havent touched in a while and have a quick question about the following code snippet:

```
private Map<String, Example> examples = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Example>();
```

...

```
public void testMethod() {
    Enumeration allExamples = examples.elements();
    while (allExamples.hasMoreElements()){
    //get the next example
    Example eg = (Example) allExamples.nextElement();
    eg.doSomething();
```

}

It had previously used a hashtable, but I have replaced that with a thread safe hash map.
My question is, what is the best way to iterate through a hashmap? as Enumeration has been deprecated. Should I just use a for each loop?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: for each is the right answer. But you do have an Iterator available if you want something more.

Comment: `HashMap#keySet().iterator();` is what you are looking for.

Comment: there's also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066589/java-iterate-through-hashmap

Answer (score 4):

yep use a [**for-each loop**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html), **for-each/enhanced loop** was introduced for the purpose of `iterating` over a collection/arrays. But you can only iterate over a collection using for-each if and only if  your collection implements [**Iterable**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) interface.

```
for(Map.Entry<String, Example> en: example.entrySet()){
System.out.println(en.getKey() + "  " + en.getValue());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you only process the values:

```
public void testMethod() 
{
    for (Example ex : allExamples.values())
    {
        ex.doSomething();
    }
}
```