# How do i store bytearray as value in hashmaps?

Tags: java, android, hashmap, linkedhashmap

i tried to store a bytearray in a LinkedHashMap

```
static Map<Long, byte[]> lhm2 = new LinkedHashMap<Long, byte[]>(1000);
```

But

```
lhm2.get(1)
```

will throw a NullPointerException. lhm2 contains key 1 and i checked if it's not null with

```
if(lhm2.get(1) != null){
    System.out.println("not null");
}
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Chris

Comment: you should use `contansKey(keyName)` to check if a key exists or not

Comment: When do you get the NPE?

Comment: Please show a short but *complete* program demonstrating your problem. I strongly suspect it's not where you think it is. That code would only fail if `lhm2` is null.

Comment: `lhm2.get(1)` can throws NPE only if you try to call a method using this object

Comment: thanks for your fast support! the comment below fixed my problem, wow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your key should be a long so better do this

```
lhm2.get(1L)
```

instead of doing like

```
lhm2.get(1)
```

Comment: what to do if i want to put it in a for-loop? is a simple cast ok? like lhm2.get((long) i)?

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066589/java-iterate-through-hashmap to iterate over your map

Answer (score 0):

You should do:

```
if(lhm2.contains(1){
    lhm2.get(1)
}
```