# Java: Iterate over nested hashmap using entrySet()

Tags: java, hashmap

I'm trying to iterate over a nested hashmap using entrySet(). The Multi-hashmap is called data, and I'm trying to search for a value inside on of the many hashmaps it contains. However, even though it seems like I reach the right place, it doesn't match my search term. When I print the values, I see that the search term is indeed one of the values in the hashmap currently in loop. Here's the code -

```
HashMap<String,HashMap<String,String>> data =  driver.data.get(dsName);

for (int i = 0; i < arrWhereValues.length; i++) {
String value = null;
for (Entry<String, HashMap<String, String>> entry : data.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println("VALUE:::" +entry.getValue());
    System.out.println("SEARCH FOR::"+arrWhereValues[i]);
    if(arrWhereValues[i].equals(entry.getKey())){
        value = entry.getKey();
        System.out.println("Value in case 1::" +value);
    }
    else if(entry.getValue().containsValue(arrWhereValues[i])){ //Why doesn't it enter here???
        System.out.println("atleast this much was correct!!");
        System.out.println(entry.getValue().entrySet());
        for (Entry<String, String> v : entry.getValue().entrySet()) { //Find a better way of doing this. 
            if(v.getValue().contains(arrWhereValues[i])){
                value = v.getKey();
                System.out.println("Value in case 2 ::"+value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
VALUE:::{name=Testing User , slug_primary=null, slug_secondary=null}
SEARCH FOR::Testing User
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: are you sure that the value of name = "Testing User" does not have trailing space? Because, for me seems like it does.

Comment: Could you post what's the requirement rather than bunch of code which is not showing what you want

Comment: @alex: Yes, that was the problem. I corrected it. Thanks.

Comment: @Reddy: This was the code I was working on. As I could not understand what I could possibly be doing wrong, I asked the question here. Thought the code would make sense after my explanation. In case it did not, my apologies.

Answer (score 0):

use a solution like this method to print the contents of all of the hash maps :

[Iterate through a HashMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066589/java-iterate-through-hashmap)

probably some of the keys / values are not what you expect - see Alex's comment that "Testing User" appears to have a trailing space.  Also it seems that "Testing User" is one of the keys in your nested hashmap, instead of in the outer hashmap where you are searching for it.

Comment: in response to the "// Find a better way of doing this" comment -
instead of looping through all the entries in the hashmap testing for equality, you can just do this once:
 myString = myHashMap.get(myKey) and then check to see if myString is null (it is null if no value is found). This is the sort of lookup HashMap is designed for!