# Java - Get map values by arrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I have question why I can't get this values

```
    HashMap<String, P> users = new HashMap<String, P>();
    users.put("john", new P("john"));

    List<String> arenaUsers = new ArrayList<String>();
    arenaUsers.add("john");

    for (String user : arenaUsers) {
        for (P p : users.get(user)) {
            System.out.println(p.getName());
        }
    }
```

**I got error:**

```
Can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable
```

But I can't iterate `Map`, How I can fix it?

Comment: What does `users.get(user)` return?

Comment: Check these two questions out:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46898/how-do-i-iterate-over-each-entry-in-a-map
and
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066589/java-iterate-through-hashmap

Comment: I don't wan't get all values from users, but only keys what are stored in arenaUsers

Comment: Check the `Map` interface and its various methods.

Comment: Sorry, I now know what I doing wrong, I wan't get Value P and not Values P.

Answer (score 0):

In Map for one key you will get only one value, thats the cause of 
"Can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable"
this happens in the second for loop, which is useless as its only one value

```
for (P p : users.get(user))
```

Instead do as:

```
for (String user : arenaUsers) {
        if(users.containsKey(user))
           System.out.println(users.get(user).getName());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here you class `p` does not implement `Iterable` so it can't be used inside the `for` loop. So to use it inside `for` loop you need to implement `Iterable` or use an existing `collection` which have already implemented `Iterable` i.e.

```
    Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
    List<String> l =new ArrayList<String>();l.add("stack");l.add("overflow");
    map.put("trying", l);
    for(String ss: map.get("trying")){
        System.out.println(ss);
    }
```

Here i have used `List` which implements `Iterable` and can be used in side the for loop.