# get all the values from a hash table

Tags: java, android, hashtable

I'm working on an Android project in which I have to get all the values from a **hash table** regardless the key. My map is

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<MyProduct>> orderAdap = InvocieProductFragment.mapOrderd;
```

And from this map I'm loading relevent Product ArrayList according to **product name**.

```
ArrayList<MyProduct> lstStyle = orderAdap.get(lstBrandCode.get(position));
```

But my problem is can I load all the Product lists into a single ArrayList without concerning **key values** in this hash map.

For instance imagine my hash map is something like this.

```
[ss,[p1,p2,p3]],[we,[p3,p4]],[rf,[p1,p4,p5,p7,p9]]
```

and I need the output as

```
[p1,p2,p3,p3,p4,p1,p4,p5,p7,p9]
```

Can this be done. Need help. Thanks.....

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get value from map list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13679427/get-value-from-map-list)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have to get all the values from a hash table regardless the key

Use the [`values()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#values%28%29) method from map :

```
Map<String, List<Integer>> m = new HashMap<>();
m.put("test", new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3)));
m.put("test2", new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(2,3,4)));

List<List<Integer>> l = new ArrayList<>(m.values());
System.out.println(l);
```

Output :

```
[[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]]
```

**EDIT :**
To have a flatten `List`

```
        List<Integer> flattenList = new ArrayList<>();
        for(List<Integer> list : m.values()){
            for(Integer i : list)
                flattenList.add(i);
        }
        System.out.println(flattenList);
```

Output :

```
[1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4]
```

[**Demo here**](http://ideone.com/Mm0UgH)

Additional note : You can check [this](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Flatten_a_list#Java) if you want to flatten a list of an arbitrary depth (using recursion)

Comment: Not this. I want the output as `[1,2,3,2,3,4]`

Answer (score 2):

> But my problem is can I load all the Product lists into a single ArrayList without concerning key values in this hash map.

You are looking for the method [values()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#values%28%29)  on `HashmMap`

> Returns a Collection view of the values contained in this map.

So it turns

```
Collection<ArrayList<MyProduct>> allValuesCollection = orderAdap.values();
```

Then you can iterate over it

```
for (ArrayList<MyProduct> eachList : allValuesCollection ) {
            //play with  eachList 
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

just iterate you map using value set and add to your list.

```
java.util.Iterator iter = hm.valueSet().iterator();

while(iter.hashNext()){

//add to your list
}
```

Comment: see ZouZou answer below

Comment: How can I add the product values in the hash map into an ArrayList. The product values in the hash map are stored in ArrayLists. So how can I get all the values in those ArrayLists into an ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

do like this

```
 Collection<ArrayList<MyProduct>> values = orderAdap.values();
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to iterate over values::
may be this will help:
[Iterate through a HashMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066589/java-iterate-through-hashmap)

```
for (Object value : map.values()) {
    // ... add values to lstStyle without worring about key
}
```

hope this helps!

Comment: How can I add the product values in the hash map into an ArrayList. The product values in the hash map are stored in ArrayLists. So how can I get all the values in those ArrayLists into an ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

```
        MyProduct myProduct1 = new MyProduct();
        myProduct1.setProductId(1);
        myProduct1.setProductName("asm");

        MyProduct myProduct2 = new MyProduct();
        myProduct2.setProductId(2);
        myProduct2.setProductName("tsm");

        MyProduct myProduct3 = new MyProduct();
        myProduct3.setProductId(2);
        myProduct3.setProductName("rsm");

        List<MyProduct> productList1 = new ArrayList<>();
        productList1.add(myProduct1);
        productList1.add(myProduct2);

        List<MyProduct> productList2 = new ArrayList<>();
        productList2.add(myProduct3);

        Map<String, List<MyProduct>> map = new HashMap<String, List<MyProduct>>();
        map.put("First", productList1);
        map.put("Second", productList2);


        Collection<List<MyProduct>> listOfList = map.values();

        for(List<MyProduct> list : listOfList){
            for(MyProduct product: list){
                System.out.println(""+ product.getProductName());   
            }

        }
```