# Java, get all variable values of a class

Tags: java, variables, for-loop, arraylist

So I have a class called Test:

```
public class Test{
    protected String name = "boy";
    protected String mainAttack = "one";
    protected String secAttack = "two";
    protected String mainType"three";
    protected String typeSpeak = "no spoken word in super class";

//Somehow put all the class variables in an Array of some sort
    String[] allStrings = ??(all class' strings);
//(and if you feel challenged, put in ArrayList without type declared.
//So I could put in, not only Strings, but also ints etc.)

    public void Tester(){
    //Somehow loop through array(list) and print values (for-loop?)
    }
}
```

As you can see, I want to put all the class variables in an Array or ArrayList (or something similar) automatically.
And next I want to be able to loop through the array and print/get the values.
Preferably using an enhanced-for loop.

Comment: Use getters and setters.

Comment: Why don't you just use an array to start with? why do you need the separate variables?

Comment: This is a terrible idea, don't ever design your classes this way. If you're doing it just to test reflection, fine. `Reflection` being the key word.

Comment: It's a small portion of my project. Just a simple example to see what my intentions are. This is not my actual code.

Answer (score 1):

As other said, don't do this. But this is how:

```
Class<?> cl = this.getClass();
List<Object> allObjects = new ArrayList<Object>();
for (java.lang.reflect.Field f: cl.getDeclaredFields())
{
    f.setAccessible(true);
    try
    {
        Object o = f.get(this);
        allObjects.add(o);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        ...
    }
}
for (Object o: allObjects)
    System.out.println(o);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really really need do this you need to use Reflection.

However a much better approach would be to store the values in a Map (probably a HashMap) and then you can query/set/etc them from that easily.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Map` or `Hashmap` to store variables and its values instead of `Array` or `Arraylist`

[HashMap](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-use-hashmap-tutorial-java/) is an object that stores both “key/value” as a pairs. In this article, we show you how to create a HashMap instance and iterates the HashMap data.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a `HashMap` for the values and iterate through that?

[Iterate through a HashMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066589/java-iterate-through-hashmap)

Comment: I understand, and you are correct. But that doesn't apply to my problem right now...

Answer (score 0):

Do this.

```
String threeEleves = "sky";
String sevenDwarves = "stone";
String nineMortal = "die";
String oneRing[] = new String[]  // <<< This
{
  threeElves,
  sevenDwarves,
  nineMortal
}
```

or do this

```
// in some class.
public void process(final String... varArgs)
{
    for (String current : varArgs)
    {
    }
}

String one = "noodles";
String two = "get";
String three = "in";
String four = "my";
String five = "belly";

process (one, two, three, four, five);
```