# Store multiple values in HashMap and get it later

Tags: java

I am storing a data in HashMap and getting the value in later stage.

```
HashMap<String, byte[]> hm = new HashMap<String, byte[]>();
```

Now, I want to store two more values into it. For example, I want to store info like below. Could someone please advise me, how can i modify the Hashmap to ahieve this way? I also require to read all these stored values and find some value from it in later stage.

```
Key 1
    IPAddress
    RandomNumber
    Byte data
Key 2
    IPAddress
    RandomNumber
    Byte data
```

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe you should consider creating a class to store these values?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create a class with these properties:

```
class MyData{
    private String IPAddress;
    private long RandomNumber;
    private byte[] data;

    //getters setters...
}

Map<String, MyData> hm = new HashMap<String, MyData>();
```

You can get the values as:

```
MyData dataObj = hm.get("Key 1");
dataObj.getRandomNumber();
```

or directly

```
  hm.get("Key 1").getData();
  hm.get("Key 1").getRandomNumber();
```

To iterate over the map:

```
    Iterator it = hm.entrySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry myDataEntry = (Map.Entry)it.next();
        System.out.println(myDataEntry.getKey() + " = " + myDataEntry.getValue());
        it.remove(); // avoids a ConcurrentModificationException
    }
```

Taken from here: [Iterate through a HashMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066589/java-iterate-through-hashmap)

Comment: OK..How to retrieve the values back? Lets say I want to read all the values and pick a particular item back? Others doubts, 1.) HashMap stores the data permanently or temporarily? 2.) Is it possible to delete a particular record from the entire list?

Comment: I edited the answer for the access to the properties. For doubt 1 - the data will be stored as long as the `hm` object is in scope/is not collected by GC. Doubt 2 - you can use the hashmap's remove method, see http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/hashmap_remove.htm

Comment: Hi, I couldn't get code to go through all data to retrieve. How can i go through all the data using for loop?

Comment: I updated the answer. To iterate with for loop see the second answer from the link.

Comment: Hi, How would i get RandomNumber() inside this loop?

Comment: I could able to get it.

Comment: entry.getValue().getRandomNumber();

Comment: thank you so much! Need urgent help, Could you please help on this query as well-> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21823938/hashmap-data-not-appending-new-data-into-arraylist

Answer (score 0):

Create a class like:

```
public class Key{
    int randomNumber;
    byte[] data;
    String ipAddress;
}
```

And store it like a value of your Map.

```
Map<String, Key> map;
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: "Key" is kind of a bad name to use with the Map, especially since the "Key" isn't the *Key*

Comment: Sure it is. I see it above in the question and use it without think about it:

Answer (score 0):

I see two options for your issue:

1 - make a bean to wrap all the needed content (as advised by other posters)

2 - if you want to have more values for a single key and adding a new library to your project is not an issue you can use google guava library, more particularly the [Multimap](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn-history/r14/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) class. There you can have more values for a single key.

Nevertheless I would advise in writing a java bean that wraps the content you want in a single object.