# HashMap data not appending new data into ArrayList

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket

I am using the following code to connect with java socket from an Applet client. I store Client's IP Address and some random number in every NEW connection happening in `addNewClient()` function in the below code. I store this info in `HashMap`. I add more client info in the `ArrayList` of this `HashMap`.

If there is already some client info in `ArrayList`, I need to read through it. I am trying that in `SocketConnection` class below using `Iterator`.

The problem I see is, I am adding some 3 client info into the `ArrayList`. But, when i read through it using `Iterator`, it can get only last added Client info, and other KEYS are just getting empty. But, at the same time, its giving the ArrayList size correctly as `3`

Could some experts please refer my below complete code, and advise me what could be the problem in there?

```
public class DataSharingSocketListner {
            public static void main(String[] args) {

                System.out.println("client trying to connect before thread creation");

                Thread thr = new Thread(new SocketThread());
                thr.start();
            }
        }

        class SocketThread implements Runnable {

            HashMap<String, ClientInfo> clientInfo = new HashMap<String, ClientInfo>();

            ArrayList<HashMap<String, ClientInfo>> myList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, ClientInfo>>();

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    System.out.println("client trying to connect after thread creation");

                    ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(8080);
                    while (true) {

                        SocketConnection client = new SocketConnection(server.accept(), clientInfo, myList);
                        client.start();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }

        class SocketConnection extends Thread {
            InputStream input;
            PrintWriter output;
            Socket socket;
            ObjectOutputStream out = null;
            OutputStream clientOutput;
            Scanner scannerObj;
            HashMap<String, byte[]> hm;
            InetAddress addr;

            HashMap<String, ClientInfo> clientinfo;

            ArrayList<HashMap<String, ClientInfo>> clientList;

            public SocketConnection(Socket socket, HashMap<String, ClientInfo> clientInfo, ArrayList<HashMap<String, ClientInfo>> myList) {

                super("Thread 1");

                this.socket = socket;
                //this.hm = dataHashMap;
                this.clientinfo = clientInfo;
                this.clientList = myList;

                try {

    // IT IS PRINTING TOTAL SIZE 3 SUCCESSFULLY HERE
                    int totalClientList = clientList.size();
                    System.out.println("totalClientList: " + totalClientList);

                    if ( totalClientList>0 )
                    {
                        for (int i=0; i<totalClientList; i++)
                        {
                            System.out.println("client list reading " + i);

                            HashMap<String, ClientInfo> tmpData = (HashMap<String, ClientInfo>) clientList.get(i);

  // IT IS GETTING ONLY THE LAST KEY, OTHER KEYS ARE SHOWING EMPTY
                            Set<String> key = tmpData.keySet();
                            Iterator it = key.iterator();

                            while (it.hasNext()) {
                                System.out.println("hasNexthasNext");
                                String hmKey = (String)it.next();
                                ClientInfo hmData = (ClientInfo) tmpData.get(hmKey);

                                System.out.println("Key: "+hmKey +" & Data: "+hmData.getRandomNo());
                                it.remove(); // avoids a ConcurrentModificationException
                            }
                        }
                        // TO ADD NEW CLIENT EVERY TIME
                        addNewClient();
                    }
                    else {
                        System.out.println("Client List shows empty");

                        // TO ADD NEW CLIENT EVERY TIME
                        addNewClient();
                    }

                    // Not used yet, will be used
                    input = socket.getInputStream();
                    scannerObj = new Scanner(socket.getInputStream());
                    clientOutput = socket.getOutputStream();


                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            public int genRandomNumber() {
                Random r = new Random( System.currentTimeMillis() );
                return 10000 + r.nextInt(20000);
            }
            String getLocalIP () {
                InetAddress inetAddress = null;
                String ipAddress = null;
                try {
                    inetAddress = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
                    ipAddress = inetAddress.getHostAddress();
                } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println("ipAddress : " + ipAddress);

                return ipAddress;
            }
            void addNewClient () {

                String ipAddress = getLocalIP();

                if ( ipAddress!=null )
                {
                    ClientInfo clientobj = new ClientInfo();

                    clientobj.setIPAdd(ipAddress);
                    int randno =  genRandomNumber();
                    System.out.println("genRandomNumber() : " + randno);
                    clientobj.setRandomNo(randno);

                    String key = String.valueOf(randno);

                    clientinfo.put(key, clientobj);

                    clientList.add(clientinfo);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void run() {

                System.out.println("Going to Read client data");

                //do something
                {
                    String hostIP = addr.getHostAddress() ;
                    System.out.println("hostIP: " + hostIP);

                    //do something
                }
            }



        }

        class ClientInfo {

            private String IPAddress;
            private long RandomNumber;
            private byte[] data;

            public static void main(String []args) {
                System.out.println("Client info Main");
            }

            //Setter
            void setIPAdd (String ip) {
                System.out.println("setIPAdd called");
                IPAddress = ip;
            }
            void setRandomNo (long randomno) {
                RandomNumber = randomno;
            }
            void setImageData (byte[] imgData) {
                data = imgData;
            }

            //Getter 
            String getIPAdd () {
                return IPAddress;
            }
            long getRandomNo () {
                return RandomNumber;
            }
            byte[] getImageData () {
                return data;
            }

        }
```

UPDATE: As per Amrish suggestion, changed the following code, it solved the issue.

```
    int totalClientList = clientList.size();
                        System.out.println("totalClientList: " + totalClientList);

                        if ( totalClientList>0 )
                        {
                            for (int i=0; i<totalClientList; i++)
                            {
                                System.out.println("client list reading " + i);

                                HashMap<String, ClientInfo> tmpData = (HashMap<String, ClientInfo>) clientList.get(i);
                                Set<String> key = tmpData.keySet();
                                System.out.println("key: " + key);
        }
                            addNewClient();
                        }
                        else {
                            System.out.println("Client List shows empty");
                            addNewClient();
                        }

    void addNewClient () {

                String ipAddress = getLocalIP(); 

                if ( ipAddress!=null )
                {
// CREATE NEW OBJECT EVERY TIME WHEN STORING
                    HashMap<String, ClientInfo> clientInfo = new HashMap<String, ClientInfo>();
                    ClientInfo clientobj = new ClientInfo();

                    //System.out.println("Test log 1" + clientobj);
                    clientobj.setIPAdd(ipAddress);
                    // System.out.println("Test log 2");
                     int randno =  genRandomNumber();
                     System.out.println("genRandomNumber() : " + randno);
                     clientobj.setRandomNo(randno);

                    String key = String.valueOf(randno);
                    //System.out.println("key: " + key);

                    clientInfo.put(key, clientobj);

                    clientList.add(clientInfo);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Arraylist has 3 hashmap but each hashmap has only one object. Hence , you are getting size as 3 but only one object is returned when you iterate over the hashmap.

Comment: I tried adding HashMap object separately for each time store, but also observed the same issue.

Comment: Well, Amrish, You found the problem is perfect! I tried adding new hasmap object each time when storing, it lists all the items properly now.

Answer (score 0):

Problem here is you are comparing two different things:

```
int totalClientList = clientList.size();
```

this will give you the number of clients you have in your list:

```
 HashMap<String, ClientInfo> tmpData = (HashMap<String, ClientInfo>) clientList.get(i);
 Set<String> key = tmpData.keySet();
```

This will give you the keys of the `i'th client`. which is different than the `total clients.`

What you should do is to `drop List of hashmaps` and just use a `single HashMap` to keep track of all the clients.

Hope this helps.

Change your SocketThread to remove list

```
class SocketThread implements Runnable {

    HashMap<String, ClientInfo> clientInfo = new HashMap<String, ClientInfo>();


    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            System.out.println("client trying to connect after thread creation");

            ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(8080);
            while (true) {

                SocketConnection client = new SocketConnection(server.accept(), clientInfo);
                client.start();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

change your SockectConnection to remove list

```
           HashMap<String, ClientInfo> clientinfo;

            public SocketConnection(Socket socket, HashMap<String, ClientInfo> clientInfo) {
                super("Thread 1");

                this.socket = socket;
                //this.hm = dataHashMap;
                this.clientinfo = clientInfo;

                try {

    // IT IS PRINTING TOTAL SIZE 3 SUCCESSFULLY HERE
                    int totalClientList = clientInfo.size();
                    System.out.println("totalClientList: " + totalClientList);

                    if ( totalClientList>0 )
                    {


  // IT IS GETTING ONLY THE LAST KEY, OTHER KEYS ARE SHOWING EMPTY
                            Set<String> key = clientInfo.keySet()
                            Iterator it = key.iterator();

                            while (it.hasNext()) {
                                System.out.println("hasNexthasNext");
                                String hmKey = (String)it.next();
                                ClientInfo hmData = (ClientInfo) tmpData.get(hmKey);

                                System.out.println("Key: "+hmKey +" & Data: "+hmData.getRandomNo());
                                it.remove(); // avoids a ConcurrentModificationException
                            }

                        // TO ADD NEW CLIENT EVERY TIME
                        addNewClient();
                    }
                    else {
                        System.out.println("Client List shows empty");

                        // TO ADD NEW CLIENT EVERY TIME
                        addNewClient();
                    }

                    // Not used yet, will be used
                    input = socket.getInputStream();
                    scannerObj = new Scanner(socket.getInputStream());
                    clientOutput = socket.getOutputStream();


                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

Change Add New Client:

```
    void addNewClient () {

        String ipAddress = getLocalIP();

        if ( ipAddress!=null )
        {
            ClientInfo clientobj = new ClientInfo();

            clientobj.setIPAdd(ipAddress);
            int randno =  genRandomNumber();
            System.out.println("genRandomNumber() : " + randno);
            clientobj.setRandomNo(randno);

            String key = String.valueOf(randno);

            clientinfo.put(key, clientobj);

        }
    }
```

I just edited your code, it should give you a start. Hope this helps.

Comment: Could you provide a sample please

Comment: This way, it will store only the last added data, it will not add into like Array list of data.

Comment: Try it.. it will add a new entry if your generated keys are different

Comment: And why you are getting just one item in the map because I  while loop you are removing every item using it.remove()

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about two different things. One is the size of a list, the other one is the size of a hashMap.
Try this:

```
int mapSize = tmpData.size();
```

You can get the size of the map and check if it's right.

Comment: I want to read the 3 data added into ArrayList. I added 3 HasMap object into ArrayList, when I'm reading it, it gives me only the last added data properly, others are showing empty.