# Return the size of an ArrayList that is a value in a HashMap

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I am working on project that is a spam filter for an email client.

```
public MailServer()
{
    mailMap = new HashMap<String,ArrayList<MailItem>>();
}
```

I was instructed to use a HashMap to store the recipients and ArrayLists to hold their mailItems. The next method is to count and return the mailItems for a specific recipient.

```
public int howManyMailItems(String who)
{
    int count = 0;
    for(MailItem item : mailMap) {
        if(item.getTo().equals(who)) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

---

**Edit**

I'm working in BlueJ and when I try to compile the class it highlights mailMap in the 4th line and says

> "for-each loop not appicable"

```
 public int howManyMailItems(String who)
{
    int count = 0;
    for(MailItem item : mailMap.keySet()) {
        if(item.getTo().equals(who)) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

When I try a keySet it says incompatible types.

Comment: um... what's wrong?? What exactly is your question?

Comment: I'm working in BlueJ and when I try to compile the class it highlights mailMap in the 4th line and says

Comment: "for-each loop not appicable"

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066589/java-iterate-through-hashmap?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Map` does not implement the `Iterable` interface. This is why you get the "for-each loop not appicable" error. You have a choice of iterating over the map's

- `entrySet()` — a `Set<Map.Entry<K,V>>` (where `K` is the key type and `V` is the value type of the map);
- `keySet()` — a `Set<K>`; or
- `values()` — a `Collection<V>`.

In general, you would want to do something like this:

```
public int howManyMailItems(String who)
{
    int count = 0;
    for(Map.Entry<String,ArrayList<MailItem>> entry : mailMap.entrySet()) {
        String key = entry.getKey();
        ArrayList<MailItem> array = entry.getValue();
        // process key and array value
    }
    return count;
}
```

It's hard to tell exactly what logic you are using to count. If you only need the arrays (and are ignoring the keys to your map), then you can use:

```
public int howManyMailItems(String who)
{
    int count = 0;
    for(ArrayList<MailItem> array : mailMap.values()) {
        for (MailItem item : array) {
            if (item.getTo().equals(who)) {
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

P.S. It's generally considered good practice to declare generic parameter types using interfaces rather than concrete types. For instance, your map could be declared:

```
Map<String, List<MailItem>>
```

rather than

```
Map<String, ArrayList<MailItem>>
```

(You would have to modify the type used in the iteration loop accordingly.) You can still put instances of `ArrayList` into the map, but you could also change your mind and put other kinds of `List`. (For instance, you could then put unmodifiable lists resulting from calls to `Collections.unmodifiableList(...)`.)

Answer (score 0):

```
public int howManyMailItems(String who) {
    return mailMap.get(who).size();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not mentioning any errors, so it's tough to know what's wrong, but usually you iterate through a Map's Key Set, obtained via `keySet()`, or through its values obtained via `values()`.

i.e.,

```
for(String key : mailMap.keySet()) {
    List<MainItem> itemList = mailMap.get(key);
    count += itemList.size(); // ??? not sure if this is what you want??
    // ... etc..
}
```

Comment: public int howManyMailItems(String who)
    { mailMap
        int count = 0;
        for(MailItem item : mailMap.keySet()) {
            if(item.getTo().equals(who)) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    } When I try to compile it highlights keySet and says incompatible types

Comment: @TvDinnerGuy7: avoid posting code in a comment since it cannot be formatted and is unreadable. Instead post it as an edit to your question.

Answer (score 0):

As you have `HashMap<String,ArrayList<MailItem>>`. The key is type of `String` and value is `ArrayList<MailItem>`. The reason of your error is that you fetch the List and try to assign it to MaiItem.

```
public int howManyMailItems(String who)
{
    int count = 0;

    if(who == null) { //Check the input before operate
      return count;
    }

    for(Iterable<MailItem> iterable : mailMap.values()) { //Interface instead of Class
        for (MailItem item : iterable) {
            if (item == null) { //It is possible that item can be null
               continue;
            }

            if (who.equals(item.getTo())) { //It is possible that To can be null
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Why to use Iterable instead of ArrayList in for-each loop ?

The advantage of that solution is that, we do not have to change the code we decide to use another `Collection` for our storage.

Why Iterable not Collection ?

In this case we perform only read operation, so this is the required minimum to solve the task. The advantage of this is greater code flexibility.