# Storing and retrieving values from hashmap

Tags: android, sqlite, hashmap

i'm a beginner to Android development .... can u please tell me if this is this the correct way to declare an hashmap and add it to the arraylist?

```
Button createagendaButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.button2);
createagendaButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
{
@Override
public void onClick(View v) 
{
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("agendaTitle", edit_agendaTitle.getText().toString());
map.put("presenterName", edit_presenterName.getText().toString()); 
mylist.add(map);
}
});
```

Comment: what are your needs ?

Comment: i've 3 edittext's in my app, whose values need to be put into hashmap

Comment: well i am afraid you dont need a hashmap , go for a direct db storage or sharedprefrences for temp storage

Comment: @SrinathGanesh i don't need these to be stored in db or shared preference .... i want these values to be put into a hashmap and store it in db .... is it possible?? how??

Comment: how to display hashmap values in logcat??

Comment: 1. [loop over a hashmap](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1066603/1897935) : 2. Log.e("data->",""+);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will allow you to store the values into the hashmap by using the key => value convention.

```
Map mMap = new HashMap();
mMap.put("FirstName", firstNameInput.getText().toString());
mMap.put("Surname", surnameInput.getText().toString());
mMap.put("Gender", genderInput.getText().toString());
```

Note, you will need to change the variable name before `.getText()` to that of your EditText variable names

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/HashMap.html might be of some use!

Comment: @JayanthGowda retain your generics (collections with <?> )

Comment: Yes, @Srinath Ganesh is right. You should probably initialise mMap using generics - something like `Map<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<String, String>();`

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are new to android
For starters why dont you go through samples in android sdk

```
sdk-path/samples/api-version/
```

and this [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/)

To cheer you up try these that will solve your problems
1. get value from edittext `edittext.getText();` 
2. store values in hashmap as `hashmap.put(key,value)` 
3. instead of going for hashmaps, reconsider the type of data you are storing and try **SparseArray** if it suits your needs. Sparse arrays are well optimized and good at performance though they are very different in comparison 
4. sqlite can store only some types of data. For sqlite on android try [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/) 
5. For ensuring proper functioning of your app across devices and resolutions, refer best practices and life cycles of different components used in your app. Also since you are using sqlite, prefer **singleton pattern**

Comment: Thank you for your valuable info.