# java map iteration and comparison

Tags: java, dictionary, iterator, comparison

How do I compare a string with the values of a key in a map?

```
HashMap<cruise,String> passengers;


public int numPeopleOnCruise(int cruiseNumber, String name) {
    HashMap<cruise,String> pass=cruise.getPassengers();
    Cruise cruise=getCruise(cruiseNumber);      
    for (String s:pass) {
        if (name.equals(s))
            count++;
    } return count;
}
```

Comment: Can you post real code?

Comment: Possible duplicate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066589/java-iterate-through-hashmap

Comment: try `pass.values().contains(name)`

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate through the entry set of the map and then access the values in the list:

You should find code to go through that here.

[Iterate through a HashMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066589/java-iterate-through-hashmap).

An idea using the code on that post:

```
public static void printMap(Map mp) {
    Iterator it = mp.entrySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry pairs = (Map.Entry)it.next();
        System.out.println(pairs.getKey() + " = " + pairs.getValue());
        if(pairs.getValue() == "something"){
            //do something
        }
    }
}
```