# How to make class executable in forEach loop?

Tags: java

If I have a class

```
public class Op {
    public Map<String, String> ops;
}
```

How can I make it executable in forEach loop?

```
for (String key : op) {
    System.out.println(op.ops.get(key))
}
```

*UPD*

Here is my solution

```
Op op = new Op(new HashMap<String, String>() {{
    put("a", "1");
    put("b", "2");
    put("c", "3");
}});

for (String key : op) System.out.println(op.map.get(key));

class Op implements Iterable<String> {    
    Map<String, String> map;
    public Op(Map<String, String> map) {
        this.map = map;
    }   
    public Iterator<String> iterator() {
        return map.keySet().iterator();
    }
}
```

But I'm not sure about verbosity. Is it too verbose? Maybe there is a much concise way to implement it?

Comment: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-generics/implementing-iterable.html

Comment: Yes. It's good example. But I don't need to write a separate Iterator class. I need a code as concise as possible, with minimal amount of lines of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are interested in looping over a SetEntry list.

```
for (Map.Entry<String, String > entry : ops.entrySet()) {
    String key = entry.getKey();
    String value = entry.getValue();
    // ...
}
```

Propable duplicate of: [Iterate through a HashMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066589/iterate-through-a-hashmap)

Answer (score 0):

In this exact case, use `#entrySet`, `#keySet` or `#values` as specified in the [API docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html).

In a general case, an object is iterable using the enhanced for loop, if it is implementing the interface `Iterable`. The most of the standard java collections are implementing this interface.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Op implements Iterable<Map.Entry<String,String>> {
public Map<String, String> ops;

@Override
public Iterator<Map.Entry<String,String>> iterator() {
    return ops.entrySet().iterator();
}
```

}

Example:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, String> n : testOp){
        System.out.println("Key: " + n.getKey() + " Value: " + n.getValue());
    }
```