# Java HashMap put in an enhanced for loop just like an ArrayList

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist, hashmap

For example, I can loop an `ArrayList` like this

```
for (String temp : arraylist)
```

Can I loop a HashMap by using the similar method?

Comment: Why don't you just try?

Comment: [Yes.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066589/iterate-through-a-hashmap).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can iterate over the keys, entries or values.

```
for (String key : map.keySet()) {
    String value = map.get(key);
}

for (String value : map.values()) {
}

for (Map.Entry<String,String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    String key = entry.getKey();
    String value = entry.getValue();
}
```

This is assuming your map has String keys and String values.

Comment: you can even do for (String temp: map.values()

Answer (score 8):

You can't directly loop a `Map` like that in Java.

You can, however, loop the keys:

```
for (SomeKeyObject key : map.keySet())
```

The values:

```
for (SomeValueObject value : map.values())
```

Or even its entries:

```
for (Map.Entry<SomeKeyObject, SomeValueObject> entry : map.entrySet())
```

Answer (score 2):

you can do

```
for (String key : hashmap.keySet()) {
    String value = hashmap.get(key);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using an **Iterator** http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html.

```
    HashMap<String, String> yourHashMap = new HashMap<>();
    Iterator<Map.Entry<String, String>> it = yourHashMap.entrySet().iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()){
        it.next();
        System.out.println(yourHashMap.get(it));
    }
```

At first sight it might be tempting to use a for-loop instead of an Iterator, but 
**you will need an Iterator if you want to modify the elements in your HashMap while iterating over them!**

When using a for-loop you cannot remove elements from your map while

```
 it.remove()
```

would work well in the above example.

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
map.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.printf("%s %s%n", k, v));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class IterableHashMap<T,U> extends HashMap implements Iterable
    {

        @Override
        public Iterator iterator() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            return this.keySet().iterator();
        }



    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {

        testA a=new testA();
        IterableHashMap test=a.new IterableHashMap<Object,Object>();
        for(Object o:test)
        {

        }
    }
```