# What is the way to get data from a HASHMAP like this?

Tags: android, hashmap

I have the next HASHMAP. What is the way to get and set data. I don't have very clear the method.

- PojoAlgoritmoCat is a Class with an ID and a NAME.
- PojoAlgoritmo is a Class with ID, NAME and CATEGORY_ID.

I don't know how to get the ID from PojoAlgoritmoCat or ID from an element of the List.

```
HashMap<PojoAlgoritmoCat, List<PojoAlgoritmo>> listDataChild;
```

Thanks.

Comment: all you have to do is ensure class PojoAlgoritmoCat CORRECTLY implements hashcode(), equals(), & compareTo() methods.

Comment: this SO answer shows looping through hashmap http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066589/iterate-through-a-hashmap