# Iterate over a java map and change values

Tags: java, android

I have a map of `<CheckBox, ImageButton>`.

I want to be able to iterate over this map and change the image of each `ImageButton`. Is there any way I can do this? `getValue()` doesn't seem to let me use the methods associated with each ImageButton.

Comment: Isn't this just iterating using `getValue()`? I'm unable to call `setImageBitmap()` on `getValue()`. It seems like I'd have to create another ImageButton object and set that equal to `getValue()`. But then if I change that new ImageButton, wont my original one stay the same?

Comment: See my updated answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066589/iterate-through-a-hashmap)

You have to cast the result of getValue to an ImageButton to use its functions.

```
Iterator it = mp.entrySet().iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
    ((ImageButton)pair.getValue()).setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}
```

Comment: You should be using generics, as the warning you're getting specifically indicates, exactly to avoid this.

Answer (score 1):

```
// support you define your hash map like this
HashMap<CheckBox,ImageButton> hs = new HashMap<CheckBox,ImageButton>();
// then
for(Map.Entry<CheckBox, ImageButton> e : hs.entrySet())
{
    ImageButton imgBtn = e.getValue();
    // do whatever you like to imgBtn
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A HashMap?
Use HashMap.values() to get a Collection of the saved Values.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#values()

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the `keys` of a `Map` using [keySet](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Map.html#keySet()), and [get](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Map.html#get(java.lang.Object)) the value associated with each individual key:

```
for (CheckBox cb : checkBoxes.keySet()) {
    ImageButton btn = checkBoxes.get(cb);
}
```