# Tracking which HashMap values have been returned

Tags: java, string, arraylist, hashmap, client-server

I have a large `HashMap<Integer, MyObject>` which is located on a server. I need to send a `String` from `MyObject` across a network to a client. My problem is that I can't figure out a good way to keep track of what `MyObject` has already been accessed to send the `String`.

I'd like it so that the client can repeatedly call the server's function to retrieve the `String`, then the client can add all the `String`s to an `ArrayList`. The server would indicate all the `String`s have been sent by returning `null`.

I can't simply send an `ArrayList<String>` of all the `String`s as I am limited to a tiny message size due to the use of RSA encryption.

The only way I've thought of so far is to keep a static instance variable `HashSet<Integer>` that holds all of the already accessed `MyObject`s. But this would mean I'd have to cross reference the `HashMap` to the `HashSet` for every lookup. There must be a better way.

Comment: you could create a custom class that does inherit from `HashMap<Integer, MyObject>` and hold a `Set<Integer>`. You just would have to override `HashMap#get` which would also add the keyValue that you are looking for into your `Set`.

Comment: If you can use an instance variable of boolean type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be a tiny example of a Map that keeps track of the keys that did get accessed. Basicly it has just overriden the `get` method of `HashMap` and additionaly adds the `Key` that did get accessed into a `Set`

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class TrackMap<K, V>  extends HashMap<K,V>{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    Set<Object> usedKeys = new HashSet<>();

    @Override
    public V get(Object key) {
        usedKeys.add(key);
        return super.get(key);
    }

    public Set<Object> getUsedKeys() {
        return usedKeys;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TrackMap<Integer, String> test = new TrackMap<>();
        for(int i = 0;i<100;++i) {
            test.put(i, Integer.toString(i));
        }
        System.out.println(test.get(5));
        System.out.println(test.get(10));
        System.out.println(test.get(15));
        System.out.println(test.get(17));
        System.out.println(test.get("what?"));

        for(Object i : test.getUsedKeys()) {
            System.out.println("The key " + i + " was accessed");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into using an iterator to access the data of the HashMap

An iterator will go through every object in the map without duplicates, and you won't need to use a set to keep track of which objects you have already accessed

[Iterate through a HashMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066589/iterate-through-a-hashmap)