# How to print key with the help of value in hashmap in android

Tags: java, android

I want to print key with the help of hashmap. Isee solution  these method but i find right solution`if(hashmapOption.containsValue(parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString()))`.
if this is true than print the key value.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Well you can iterate through all the entries in the map, check whether the value matches and print the key if so. But: a) that's slow; basically HashMap is designed for lookup by key, not value; b) there may be multiple matching values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must [iterate all entries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066589/iterate-through-a-hashmap) and print if containing:

```
// your map is map = HashMap<String, String>
public void printIfContainsValue(Map mp, String value) {
    Iterator it = map.entrySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry) it.next();
        // print if found
        if (value.equals(pair.getValue())) {
            System.out.println(pair.getKey() + " = " + pair.getValue());
        }
        it.remove(); // avoids a ConcurrentModificationException
    }
}
```

Or return the `Entry` and do what you want with it:

```
// your map is map = HashMap<String, String>
public Map.Entry containsValue(Map mp, String value) {
    Iterator it = map.entrySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry) it.next();
        // return if found
        if (value.equals(pair.getValue())) {
            return pair;
        }
        it.remove(); // avoids a ConcurrentModificationException
    }
    return null;
}
```

**NOTE:** as pointed by [John Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) you must know that:

1. that's slow; basically `HashMap` is designed for lookup by `key`, not `value`;
2. **there may be multiple matching values**, this methods will only return first found `value`.